# Understanding [ClassOne, ClassTwo].each(&:my_method)

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

I was watching a railscast and saw this code.

```
[Category, Product].(&:delete_all)
```

In regards to clearing a database.

I asked about the line in IRC and was told

```
(&:delete_all)
```

was a shortcut for

```
{|model| model.delete_all}
```

I tested this with the following

```
class ClassOne
  def class_method
    puts 1
  end
end

class ClassTwo
  def class_method
    puts 2
  end
end

[ClassOne, ClassTwo].each(&:class_method)
```

I received an error saying

```
Wrong Argument type Symbol (expected Proc)
```

I also tried

```
one = ClassOne.new
two = ClassTwo.new

[one, two].each(&:class_method)
```

But that still failed.

If I modified it to read

```
[one, two].each{|model| model.class_method}
```

Everything worked as expected.

So, what does `&:delete_all` actually do? The docs say `delete_all` is a method, so I am confused as to what is going on here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This relies upon a Ruby 1.9 extension that can be done in 1.8 by including the following:

```
class Symbol
    def to_proc
      proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
    end
end
```

I believe Rails defines this in `ActiveSupport`.

Comment: This is correct; if you ran your test in irb, it wouldn't work (assuming you're running Ruby 1.8.x). Try it again in script/console.

Answer (score 3):

It's some Rails specific patching of Ruby, [symbol to proc](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand).

Comment: This answer used to be true, but Ruby 1.8.6 and earlier is truly legacy now.