# What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators, parameter-passing

I found this code in [a RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes):

```
def tag_names
  @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

What does the `(&:name)` in `map(&:name)` mean?

Comment: I have heard this called “pretzel colon”, by the way.

Comment: Haha. I know that as an Ampersand. I have never heard it called a "pretzel" but that makes sense.

Comment: Also you can drop out the brackets `tags.map &:name` for the extra shortest entry.

Comment: Calling it "pretzel colon" is misleading, although catchy. There is no "&:" in ruby. The ampersand (&) is a "unary ampersand operator" with a pushed together :symbol. If anything, it's a "pretzel symbol". Just saying.

Comment: tags.map(&:name) is sort from of tags.map{|s| s.name}

Comment: https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-ruby-idiom-map-with-symbol/

Answer (score 551, accepted):

It's shorthand for `tags.map(&:name.to_proc).join(' ')`

If `foo` is an object with a `to_proc` method, then you can pass it to a method as `&foo`, which will call `foo.to_proc` and use that as the method's block.

The `Symbol#to_proc` method was originally added by ActiveSupport but has been integrated into Ruby 1.8.7. This is its implementation:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new do |obj, *args|
      obj.send self, *args
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: tags.map(:name.to_proc) is itself a shorthand for tags.map { |tag| tag.name }

Comment: this isn't valid ruby code, you still need the `&`, i.e `tags.map(&:name.to_proc).join(' ')`

Comment: Symbol#to_proc is implemented in C, not in Ruby, but that's what it'd look like in Ruby.

Comment: @banister I think you can write `tags.map(&:name).join(' ')` without the `to_proc`

Comment: "A block may be associated with a method call using either a literal block .. or a parameter containing a reference to a Proc or Method object prefixed with an ampersand character."  http://bit.ly/n8GpYw

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it was first added in Ruby on Rails, using that code. It was then added as a native ruby feature in version 1.8.7.

Comment: Great answer! I think a link to show the entire Symbol implementation class would be useful. https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/symbol19.rb

Comment: @SimoneCarletti - While `tags.map { |tag| tag.name }` is effectively what `tags.map(&:name.to_proc)` does, it is not exactly shorthand, per se. This is because procs can be converted to blocks, using the & operator, when they are passed to methods that use yield and thus require a block. (See the Ruby documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion)). As Josh Lee showed in his post above, symbols can also be converted to procs and, from there, can then be converted to a block, which is necessary because map uses blocks.

Comment: I found a great article to explain more detailed ampersand operator in Ruby, hope it helps people. The "foo" followed "&" can be either a symbol or an Object.   http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: @JaredBeck had it right: the ampersand just tells ruby that _"this argument is the block, try your best to make it one if it ain't yet"_

Comment: You should use `#__send__` instead of `#send` at it's safer. An object can override `send` for some reason (eg. sending emails), but if you do the same with `#__send__`, Ruby VM throws a warning.

Comment: it doesn't talk about how symbols are mapped/connected to actual methods. Symbol to proc sounds all good. But symbols are empty how do they become block of code.

Comment: It's not just a shorthand, but also 20% faster and more idiomatic ruby code.

Comment: `If foo is an object with a to_proc method, then you can pass it to a method as &foo`.  Please illustrate with an example, it's way too abstract for me. What is `&foo` language construct even called? Don't know what to google to make this more clear.

Comment: Wait -- `&:name` is shorthand for `&:name.to_proc`? If `&:name` unrolls to `&:name.to_proc`, then can't we apply the same "unroll" on that result, yielding `&:name.to_proc.to_proc`, ad infinitum? This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 199):

Another cool shorthand, unknown to many, is

```
array.each(&method(:foo))
```

which is a shorthand for

```
array.each { |element| foo(element) }
```

By calling `method(:foo)` we took a `Method` object from `self` that represents its `foo` method, and used the `&` to signify that it has a `to_proc` [method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) that converts it into a `Proc`.

This is very useful when you want to do things *point-free* style. An example is to check if there is any string in an array that is equal to the string `"foo"`. There is the conventional way:

```
["bar", "baz", "foo"].any? { |str| str == "foo" }
```

And there is the point-free way:

```
["bar", "baz", "foo"].any?(&"foo".method(:==))
```

The preferred way should be the most readable one.

Comment: `array.each{|e| foo(e)}` is shorter still :-) +1 anyways

Comment: Could you map a constructor of another class using `&method` ?

Comment: @finishingmove yeah I guess. Try this `[1,2,3].map(&Array.method(:new))`

Comment: Spoiler: the result is `[[nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]` - this could get useful.

Answer (score 84):

It's equivalent to

```
def tag_names
  @tag_names || tags.map { |tag| tag.name }.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 69):

```
tags.map(&:name)
```

**is The same as**

```
tags.map{|tag| tag.name}
```

`&:name` just uses the symbol as the method name to be called.

Comment: Can I do this with multiple values, like `tags.map(&:name, &:id)`.

Comment: @Qasim You can't do it, but you can do it like this `tags.map { |t| t.name.to_s << t.age.to_s }`

Answer (score 52):

While let us also note that ampersand `#to_proc` magic can work with any class, not just Symbol. Many Rubyists choose to define `#to_proc` on Array class:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    proc { |receiver| receiver.send *self }
  end
end

# And then...

[ 'Hello', 'Goodbye' ].map &[ :+, ' world!' ]
#=> ["Hello world!", "Goodbye world!"]
```

Ampersand `&` works by sending `to_proc` message on its operand, which, in the above code, is of Array class. And since I defined `#to_proc` method on Array, the line becomes:

```
[ 'Hello', 'Goodbye' ].map { |receiver| receiver.send( :+, ' world!' ) }
```

Answer (score 41):

It's shorthand for `tags.map { |tag| tag.name }.join(' ')`

Comment: Nope, it's in Ruby 1.8.7 and above.

Comment: Is it a simple idiom for map or Ruby always interpret the '&' in a particular way?

Comment: @collimarco: As jleedev says in his answer, the unary `&` operator calls `to_proc` on its operand. So it's not specific to the map method, and in fact works on any method that takes a block and passes one or more arguments to the block.

Answer (score 19):

Two things are happening here, and it's important to understand both.

As described in other answers, the `Symbol#to_proc` method is being called.

But the reason `to_proc` is being called on the symbol is because it's being passed to `map` as a block argument. Placing `&` in front of an argument in a method call causes it to be passed this way. This is true for any Ruby method, not just `map` with symbols.

```
def some_method(*args, &block)
  puts "args: #{args.inspect}"
  puts "block: #{block.inspect}"
end

some_method(:whatever)
# args: [:whatever]
# block: nil

some_method(&:whatever)
# args: []
# block: #<Proc:0x007fd23d010da8>

some_method(&"whatever")
# TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Proc)
# (String doesn't respond to #to_proc)
```

The `Symbol` gets converted to a `Proc` because it's passed in as a block. We can show this by trying to pass a proc to `.map` without the ampersand:

```
arr = %w(apple banana)
reverse_upcase = proc { |i| i.reverse.upcase }
reverse_upcase.is_a?(Proc)
=> true

arr.map(reverse_upcase)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
# (map expects 0 positional arguments and one block argument)

arr.map(&reverse_upcase)
=> ["ELPPA", "ANANAB"]
```

Even though it doesn't need to be converted, the method won't know how to use it because it expects a block argument. Passing it with `&` gives `.map` the block it expects.

Answer (score 15):

Josh Lee's answer is almost correct except that the equivalent Ruby code should have been as follows.

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new do |receiver|
      receiver.send self
    end
  end
end
```

not

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new do |obj, *args|
      obj.send self, *args
    end
  end
end
```

With this code, when `print [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].map(&:first)` is executed, Ruby splits the first input `[1,'a']` into 1 and 'a' to give `obj` 1 and `args*` 'a' to cause an error as Fixnum object 1 does not have the method self (which is :first).

---

When `[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].map(&:first)` is executed;

1. `:first` is a Symbol object, so when `&:first` is given to a map method as a parameter, Symbol#to_proc is invoked.
2. map sends call message to :first.to_proc with parameter `[1,'a']`, e.g., `:first.to_proc.call([1,'a'])` is executed.
3. to_proc procedure in Symbol class sends a send message to an array object (`[1,'a']`) with parameter (:first), e.g., `[1,'a'].send(:first)` is executed.
4. iterates over the rest of the elements in `[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]` object.

This is the same as executing `[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].map(|e| e.first)` expression.

Comment: Josh Lee's answer is _absolutely_ correct, as you can see by thinking about `[1,2,3,4,5,6].inject(&:+)` - inject expects a lambda with two parameters (memo and item) and `:+.to_proc` delivers it - `Proc.new |obj, *args| { obj.send(self, *args) }` or `{ |m, o| m.+(o) }`

Answer (score 5):

(&:name) is short for (&:name.to_proc) it is same as `tags.map{ |t| t.name }.join(' ')`

to_proc is actually implemented in C

Answer (score 5):

**map(&:name)** takes an enumerable object (tags in your case) and runs the name method for each element/tag, outputting each returned value from the method.

It is a shorthand for

```
array.map { |element| element.name }
```

which returns the array of element(tag) names

Answer (score 5):

First, `&:name` is a shortcut for `&:name.to_proc`, where `:name.to_proc` returns a `Proc` (something that is similar, but not identical to a lambda) that when called with an object as (first) argument, calls the `name` method on that object.

Second, while `&` in `def foo(&block) ... end` converts a block passed to `foo` to a `Proc`, it does the opposite when applied to a `Proc`.

Thus, `&:name.to_proc` is a block that takes an object as argument and calls the `name` method on it, i. e. `{ |o| o.name }`.

Answer (score 4):

Although we have great answers already, looking through a perspective of a beginner I'd like to add the additional information:

> What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?

This means, that you are passing another method as parameter to the map function. 
(In reality you're passing a symbol that gets converted into a proc. But this isn't that important in this particular case).

What is important is that you have a `method` named `name` that will be used by the map method as an argument instead of the traditional `block` style.

Answer (score 2):

It basically execute the method call `tag.name` on each tags in the array.

It is a simplified ruby shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a &: operator in Ruby. What you are seeing is the & operator applied to a :symbol.

In a method argument list, the & operator takes its operand, converts it to a Proc object if it isn't already (by calling to_proc on it) and passes it to the method as if a block had been used.

my_proc = Proc.new { puts "foo" }

my_method_call(&my_proc) # is identical to:
my_method_call { puts "foo" }

Answer (score 1):

Here `:name` is the symbol which point to the method `name` of tag object.
When we pass `&:name` to `map`, it will treat `name` as a proc object. 
For short, `tags.map(&:name)` acts as:

```
tags.map do |tag|
  tag.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

it means

```
array.each(&:to_sym.to_proc)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is same as below:

```
def tag_names
  if @tag_names
    @tag_names
  else
    tags.map{ |t| t.name }.join(' ')
end
```