# Ruby question - == nil or nil?

Tags: ruby, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [obj.nil? vs. obj == nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972266/obj-nil-vs-obj-nil)

I found a question - which one is better `== nil` or `nil`?
I always thought that these 2 things do the same. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

There is one difference: A class may define nil? as true:

```
class X
  def nil?()
    true
  end
end

puts X.new.nil? #-> true
```

Or a practical example (i don't recommend it, if you need it, I would define a nil_or_empty?):

```
class String
  def nil?()
    return empty?
  end
end

puts 'aa'.nil? #-> false
puts ''.nil? #-> true
```

---

Running a benchmark nil? seems to be a bit faster.

```
require 'benchmark'

TEST_LOOPS = 100_000_000

C_A = nil
C_B = 'aa'

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('nil?') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      x = C_A.nil?
      x = C_B.nil?
   }            #Testloops
  }
  b.report('==nil') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      x = ( C_A == nil )
      x = ( C_B == nil )
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

} #Benchmark
```

Result:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
nil?       27.454000   0.000000  27.454000 ( 27.531250)
==nil      31.000000   0.000000  31.000000 ( 31.078125)
----------------------------------- total: 58.454000sec

                user     system      total        real
nil?       27.515000   0.000000  27.515000 ( 27.546875)
==nil      31.125000   0.000000  31.125000 ( 31.171875)
```

Comment: It's probably a really bad idea to re-implement `nil?` because it will cause all kinds of chaos.

Comment: You could re-implement `==` (and related methods) so that `X.new == nil` returns true.

Comment: You are right - ruby is always more flexible as expected ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although the two operations are very different I'm pretty sure they will always produce the same result. (One calls the `#nil?` method of a NilClass object and one compares against the `nil` singleton.)

I would suggest that when in doubt you go a third way, actually, and just test the truth value of an expression.

So, `if x` and not `if x == nil` or `if x.nil?`, in order to have this test DTRT when the expression value is *false*.