# ruby koans comment

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [obj.nil? vs. obj == nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972266/obj-nil-vs-obj-nil)

Working through ruby koans now and found this comment embedded in one of the .rb files:

```
    # THINK ABOUT IT:
#
# Is it better to use
#    obj.nil?
# or
#    obj == nil
# Why?
```

I know from convention the answer is obj.nil? but I could not tell you why.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking this one again and the answer is just because it is more concise??

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because it is more common to override `#==` method than `#nil?` method. So `obj.nil?` will more reliably do what it is expected to do.

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you.