# What is this &:last Ruby construct called?

Tags: ruby, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

What are things like `survey.map(&:questions).flatten.compact` called, so I can find more information about them :).  What problems does that `&:` solve, or what is it doing exactly?  Is it used in other languages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is shorthand for:

```
survey.map { |s| s.questions }.flatten.compact
```

It's the `Symbol#to_proc` method. It used to be a part of Rails' ActiveSupport, but has since been added to Ruby syntax.

As far as performance goes, I wrote a quick benchmark script to get an idea of performance effect in both 1.8 and 1.9.

```
require 'benchmark'

many = 500
a = (1..10000).to_a

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('block once') { a.map { |n| n.to_s } }
  x.report('to_proc once') { a.map(&:to_s) }
  x.report('block many') { many.times { a.map { |n| n.to_s } } }
  x.report('to_proc many') { many.times { a.map(&:to_s) } }
end
```

First off, before giving you the results - if you weren't already sure that Ruby 1.9 was a huge speed improvement in general, prepare to be blown away.

### Ruby 1.8 results:

```
                user        system      total       real
block once      0.020000    0.000000    0.020000    (  0.016781)
to_proc once    0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.013881)
block many      6.680000    1.100000    7.780000    (  7.780532)
to_proc many    7.370000    0.540000    7.910000    (  7.902935)
```

### Ruby 1.9 results:

```
                user        system      total       real
block once      0.010000    0.000000    0.010000    (  0.011433)
to_proc once    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    (  0.004929)
block many      4.060000    0.000000    4.060000    (  4.057013)
to_proc many    2.810000    0.000000    2.810000    (  2.810312)
```

First off: Wow. Ruby 1.9 is fast. But the more relevant conclusions we draw here are interesting:

- In both cases, for only one run, `to_proc` is clearly faster. In 1.8 on the many-times run, it's tad slower. This seems to indicate that the only real performance bottleneck is creating all those Proc objects.
- In Ruby 1.9, however, the `to_proc` method is clearly much faster than blocks, no matter how many times you do it. In this case, you not only get cleaner code, but improved performance, as well.

In the end, no matter which version you're using, `to_proc` is clearly not enough of a performance issue to be worth not using - in fact, it sometimes speeds things up!

Comment: +1 Yuppers! It calls a method on the object in question. Nice example.

Comment: is there a specific term for it perhaps, is it used in other languages?

Comment: `Symbol#to_proc` is the best I can find for it. Perhaps more Googling will turn up better...

Comment: ...nope, even the best blogs leave it at just that name, from what I can find. Seems to be a fairly Ruby-unique construct, especially since it's pretty much a type-coercion hack.

Comment: using the &: notation takes significantly longer to execute

Comment: thank you! love that kind of info, any sources??

Comment: @klochner: Longer than... what? Longer than `.map(:questions.to_proc)`? Longer than `.map {|s| s.questions}`? Both? Something else?

Comment: http://blog.thoughtfolder.com/2008-02-25-a-detailed-explanation-of-ruby-s-symbol-to-proc.html - says it's a 20% performance hit as opposed to a block

Comment: I believe the version implemented in Ruby 1.9 doesn't have this performance penalty.

Comment: anyone have 1.8 and 1.9 on the same machine?  Let's test it.

Comment: 1.8 vs 1.9 benchmark added. Surprising results, and I had never noticed just how much faster 1.9 is!