# Why might a proc run faster than a block?

Tags: ruby, internals

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2211760/4376) on another question says that

```
array.map(&:to_s)
```

is faster than

```
array.map { |n| n.to_s }
```

In the first example, `&` turns `:to_s` into a Proc. The second example uses a block.

Why might a Proc be faster than a block in that benchmark? Is there some optimization that this technique allows the interpreter to do?

Comment: +1, great question, although the answers will be specific to each Ruby implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have been said this is specifically about `Symbol#to_proc` rather than procs in general and it is almost certainly ruby implementation dependant. Before `Symbol#to_proc` was in ruby itself, the pure ruby implementations of it were definitely slower the the equivalent block.

For a real answer you'd want to profile ruby while you're executing such a benchmark.

My reading of the ruby source code is that when you call `Symbol#to_proc` the proc you get is a bit special: The body of the proc is just a C api call (`rb_funcall_passing_block`), whereas in the other cases it's actual ruby code which takes a little longer to execute.

Answer (score 7):

It is not really about "proc vs block".

Here is a simple experiment (feel free to copy and run):

```
require 'benchmark'

many = 500
array = (1..10000).to_a

proc = proc { |a| a.to_s }

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('Symbol#to_proc') { many.times { array.map(&:to_s) } }
  x.report('proc') { many.times { array.map(&proc) }  }
  x.report('block') { many.times { array.map { |a| a.to_s } }  }
end
```

**Ruby 1.9.3p194 results:**

```
                user     system      total        real
Symbol#to_proc  1.170000   0.000000   1.170000 (  1.169055)
proc            1.450000   0.000000   1.450000 (  1.454216)
block           1.450000   0.000000   1.450000 (  1.448094)
```

As you see, `block` and `proc` both take virtually the same amount of CPU time. The magic is inside `Symbol#to_proc` itself.

Comment: That is a very strange result. I would have guessed that re-using the same Proc object would be faster than repeatedly creating one from a symbol. Maybe the interpreter somehow skips the work of creating a Proc at all and simply does what the proc would have done? (Update: ah, that's what @FrederickCheung says.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but perhaps it's because the Proc doesn't need to hold onto the context of the call the same way as the block.  The block needs to know variables declared outside of it, the Proc does not.

Comment: I have add here, that Proc in Ruby is a closure too (i.e. saves the context). There is a very simple test to ensure: https://gist.github.com/3109708