# How to sort a Ruby Hash by number value?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a counter hash that I am trying to sort by count. The problem I am running into is that the default Hash.sort function sorts numbers like strings rather than by number size.

i.e. Given Hash:

```
metrics = {"sitea.com" => 745, "siteb.com" => 9, "sitec.com" => 10 }
```

Running this code:

```
metrics.sort {|a1,a2| a2[1]<=>a1[1]}
```

will return a sorted array:

```
[ 'siteb.com', 9, 'sitea.com', 745, 'sitec.com', 10]
```

Even though 745 is a larger number than 9, 9 will appear first in the list. When trying to show who has the top count, this is making my life difficult. :)

Any ideas on how to sort a hash (or an array even) by number value size?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: what ruby version do you use? your sort result is very strange

Answer (score 319, accepted):

No idea how you got your results, since it would not sort by string value... You should reverse `a1` and `a2` in your example

Best way in any case (as per Mladen) is:

```
metrics = {"sitea.com" => 745, "siteb.com" => 9, "sitec.com" => 10 }
metrics.sort_by {|_key, value| value}
  # ==> [["siteb.com", 9], ["sitec.com", 10], ["sitea.com", 745]]
```

If you need a hash as a result, you can use `to_h` (in Ruby 2.0+)

```
metrics.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.to_h
  # ==> {"siteb.com" => 9, "sitec.com" => 10, "sitea.com", 745}
```

Comment: or simply `sort_by{|k,v| v}`

Comment: My number was returning as a string, that fixed it.. I had a2 and a1 in that order because I wanted the results to sort decending.. thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: one note is that if your keys are symbols you might have to convert them to strings.

Comment: @engineerDave: Did you mean if your values are symbols? In any case, that's incorrect as `Symbol`s are comparable to one another.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: Not if they can't be coerced to strings? I'm a little stymied on this one. :) Welcoming any clarification. Perhaps a visual example can clarify. https://gist.github.com/nacengineer/5577868

Comment: @engineerDave: No idea how you get your results. `h2.sort` works in Ruby 1.9x or 2.0.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: nevermind. must have been Gremlins in irb. its working now. thanks!

Comment: don't forget you get an [] back instead of an {}

Comment: if you want to revert it to hash for, I found the following working: `metrics.sort_by{ |k, v| v }.inject(Hash.new){ |h, a| h.merge!({a[0] => a[1]}) }`

Comment: @Elchin: you can use `metrics.sort_by{ |k, v| v }.reverse.to_h`

Comment: Actually even simpler as: hash.sort_by(&:last) with the same caveat about getting an array of pairs vs. a Hash.

Comment: Hi @Marc-AndréLafortune, I have a small question why add a underscore at begin of key. This coding style mean what?

Comment: @lazybios See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689673/marking-an-unused-block-variable

Comment: for reverse sort you may use `metrics.sort_by{|k,v| -v}`

Comment: Awesome. I came up with this way which is ugly, IMO `metrics.invert.sort.reverse.to_h.invert` Using the `#invert` method of `Hash` class

Answer (score 104):

Since value is the last entry, you can do:

```
metrics.sort_by(&:last)
```

Comment: This is awesome! any referecne for the pre-definition of `&:last`?

Comment: `sort_by(&:last)` is effectively shorthand for `sort_by {|x| x.last}` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 15):

Already answered but still. Change your code to:

```
metrics.sort {|a1,a2| a2[1].to_i <=> a1[1].to_i }
```

Converted to strings along the way or not, this will do the job.

Answer (score 11):

That's not the behavior I'm seeing:

```
irb(main):001:0> metrics = {"sitea.com" => 745, "siteb.com" => 9, "sitec.com" =>
 10 }
=> {"siteb.com"=>9, "sitec.com"=>10, "sitea.com"=>745}
irb(main):002:0> metrics.sort {|a1,a2| a2[1]<=>a1[1]}
=> [["sitea.com", 745], ["sitec.com", 10], ["siteb.com", 9]]
```

Is it possible that somewhere along the line your numbers are being converted to strings?  Is there more code you're not posting?

Comment: Ahh your right it looks like the result in my code was returning it as a string. Pesky data types. :) Sometimes I am just too close to the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Yup. Occasionally I hear someone refer to Ruby as "untyped".  Oh, no, it's definitely typed.  It's just not statically typed.  :)