# How to sort nested hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

```
example_hash = {
  "1" => {"occurence": 12, "display": ""},
  "2" => {"occurence": 15, "display": ""},
  "3" => {"occurence": 16, "display": ""}
}
```

For the given above nested hash, how do we sort (descending) it based on the occurrence value. The result should display the keys in the sorted order [3,2,1]

Comment: `example_hash.sort_by{|k, v| v[:occurence]}.reverse!.to_h`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a Ruby Hash by number value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540435/how-to-sort-a-ruby-hash-by-number-value)

Answer (score 4):

```
example_hash.sort_by { |_,h| -h[:occurrence] }
  #=> [["3", {:occurrence=>16, :display=>""}],
  #    ["2", {:occurrence=>15, :display=>""}],
  #    ["1", {:occurrence=>12, :display=>""}]]
```

Tack on `.to_h` if a hash is desired, but one does not normally desire a hash with keys sorted in a particular way.

Comment: SHAZAM! For us knuckle heads that are still ham fisting with `sort{|a,b| ...}`, could you say a little more about that syntax?

Comment: @jvillian, there's not much to say, it's just the method [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). One advantage of that over `sort` is that `h["occurrence"]` is calculated just once for each value (hash), rather than twice for each pairwise-comparison with `sort`.

Comment: I suppose I was thrown by the underscore in the `|_,h|` bit. How does that underscore work? Also, the `-h[:occurrence]`. I guess the `-` in front of the `h` means descending?

Comment: @jvillian, one Ruby convention is to represent a block variable with an underscore when it's not used in the block calculation ('hey, reader I'm not using this variable in this block"). Here that variable represents a hash key. While `_` is a valid local variable, it differs from variable names that do not begin with an underscore in that Ruby allows it to be used to represent more than one local variable (e.g., `{ |_,_,x|...}` or `_,x,_ = [1,2,3]`). Sometimes you might see `{ |_k,h|...}` when `_k` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

In console, this:

```
example_hash.sort{|a,b| b[1][:occurence] <=> a[1][:occurence]}.to_h
```

returns this:

```
{"3"=>{:occurence=>16, :display=>""}, "2"=>{:occurence=>15, :display=>""}, "1"=>{:occurence=>12, :display=>""}}
```

BTW, I believe you've misspelled 'occurence'.