# How to copy a (Active)record between tables, partially?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In two tables mapped to ActiveRecord with unknown number of identical columns, e.g.:

```
  Table A      Table B
 ---------    ---------
  id           id
  name         name
  age          email
  email        is_member
```

How can I (elegantly) copy all identical attributes from a record of `Table A` to a record of `Table B`, except the `id` attribute?

For the example tables above, `name` and `email` fields should be copied.

Comment: Do you want to write a script that copies the all the records from A just this one time? Or is this something that should happen everytime a new record gets added to A?

Comment: What constitutes identical columns? is it same name and data type?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu Same column name. Date type can be assumed identical if column name is identical

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

Get intersection of the columns between TableA and TableB

```
columns = (TableA.column_names & TableB.column_names) - ["id"]
```

Now iterate through TableA rows and create the TableB rows.

```
TableB.create( TableA.all(:select => columns.join(",") ).map(&:attributes) )
```

Edit:  Copying one record:

```
table_a_record = TableA.first(:select => columns.join(","), :conditions => [...])
TableB.create( table_a_record.attributes)
```

Comment: thx. what is the meaning of `.map(&:attributes)`? EDIT: found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: the current answer will copy all records from `TableA`. How to copy only one record?

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Migt consider using a union function on the acitverecord attributes hash between the 2 tables. It's not a complete answer but may help