# How to copy partial record with ActiveRecord when PostgreSQL/JDBC automatically re-adds 'id' column?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to copy (partial) records between tables using ActiveRecord 3.2 and PostgreSQL under JRuby 1.7.

The guidance offered by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723168/how-to-copy-a-activerecord-between-tables-partially/3723463#3723463), is great and works under Ruby, but not under JRuby when operating with the `activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter`.

My two models (`Parties` and `Holders`) have (nearly) identical attributes. I remove the common "id" column so it's not copied, and keep the intersection of the columns:

`columns = (Party.column_names & Holder.column_names) - ["id"]`

Then, I create new Party records based on specific Holder records:

`parties_created = 
Party.create(Holder.where(:title_id => @title.id).all(:select => columns.join(",") ).map(&:attributes))`

And, even though I confirm that `columns` does not include the "id" column

`columns are: ["first_name", "middle_name", "other_name"]`

the jdbc adapter insists on including it:

`SQL (11.0ms)  INSERT INTO "parties" ("first_name", "id", "middle_name", "other_name") VALUES ('JOHN', NULL, 'HENRY', 'SMITH') RETURNING "id"
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

How do I tell the adapter to keep the "id" column out of things? 
Can anyone suggest a work-around?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: What happens if you manually `Party.create(:first_name => 'a', :middle_name => 'b', :other_name => 'c')`?

Comment: The JDBC adapter should do nothing of the sort. It'll add `RETURNING "id"` but it'll never alter the `INSERT` list. Something at a higher level in the stack is generating that query, and that's where you need to look.