# Rails 4, how to ordering using custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I want to order the `Conversation` model, using a custom method.

I found some solution:

[How do you order by a custom model method that has no attribute in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055799/how-do-you-order-by-a-custom-model-method-that-has-no-attribute-in-sql)

and

http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/10/11/sorting-a-rails-resource-based-on-a-calculated-value/ ,

but `Conversation` order have priority.

First-  `answer_percent desc`,
second- order to `last_answer` time 
(using custom model method `last_answered_to_i` ).

`last_answered_to_i`  method source:

```
def last_answered_to_i
  if Conversation.where(company_id: self.id, is_answered: true).present?
    last_conversation = Conversation.where(company_id: self.id, is_answered: true).first
    if last_conversation.answered_at.blank? || last_conversation.asked_at.blank?
      minutes =  (Time.now- last_conversation.updated_at)/1.minutes
    else
      minutes =  (last_conversation.answered_at - last_conversation.asked_at)/1.minutes
    end
    minutes.to_i
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

after ordering I want add pagination using `kaminari` gem.

```
@lists = Company.searchable.order("answer_percent desc").page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

How do I order by column and custom method and add pagination?

Comment: what do your relationships look like for `Conversation` to `Company` seems you could handle this with a scope depending. Also where is `last_answered_to_i` defined?

Comment: @engineersmnky Company has_many Conversation and method defind Conversation Model

Comment: So you want to return all the conversations for a company or for all companies? sorted by `[-conversation.answer_percentage,conversation.last_answered_to_i]`? Just trying to understand the desired output so that I can devise an appropriate answer.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes I wanna sort by [-conversation.answer_percentage,conversation.last_answered_to_i]. And result ActiveRecord is  Conversation for all company

Comment: @engineersmnky  Sort by All Company using Company's all conversation answer percent( simply  answer_count / question_count * 100) and companys last conversation's answered Term(using last_answered_to_i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer depends on what you want to see in the view because some of the problem could actually be solved in how you call @lists there.  Also, some of the links you found make sorting by a model method sound more difficult than it is.

In your case, you can sort your conversations by a custom method like so:
`Conversation.all.sort_by(&:custom_method)`

Or specifically:
`Conversation.all.sort_by(&:last_answered_to_i)`

Specifically, you cannot use SQL to sort or order by something not in the actual database, so you use the Ruby sort_by method.  For more info on the ampersand, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby).

For your actual view, I'm not sure really how you want to organize it.  I recently did something where I needed to group my resource by another resource called "categories", and then sort the original resource by "netvotes" which was a custom model method, then order by name.  I did it by:

- Ordering by name in the controller: `@resources = Resource.order(:name)`
- Grouping by category in the outer loop of the view: `<% @resources.group_by(&:category).each do |category, resources| %>`
- Then sorting the resources by votes in the partial for resources: `<%= render resources.sort_by(&:netvotes).reverse %>`

The view is a bit confusing, so here is the full view loop in index.html.erb:

```
<% @resources.group_by(&:category).each do |category, resources| %>
  <div class="well">
    <h3 class="brand-text"><%= category.name %></h3>
    <%= render resources.sort_by(&:netvotes).reverse %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the _resource.html.erb partial:

```
<div class="row resource">
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
    <div class="vote-box">
      <%= link_to fa_icon('chevron-up lg'), upvote_resource_path(resource), method: :put %><br>
      <%= resource.netvotes %><br>
      <%= link_to fa_icon('chevron-down lg'), downvote_resource_path(resource), method: :put %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= link_to resource.name, resource.link, target: "_blank" %>
    <p><%= resource.notes %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that helps you think through some more ways to address your problem.