# Merging arrays without losing original order, ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge

I have an array structure that looks like:

```
a=[
  [['a','A'],['b','B'],['c','C']],
  [['d','D'],['e','E'],['f','F']]
]
```

How to merge inner two arrays so the new structure will be Array of arrays

```
[
 ['a','A'],['b','B'],['c','C'],['d','D'],['e','E'],['f','F']
]
```

Tried

```
a.inject([]){|k,v| v | k} # but order gets changed
=> [["d", "D"], ["e", "E"], ["f", "F"], ["a", "A"], ["b", "B"], ["c", "C"]]
```

How can i get desired result without loosing the order.

Tips, comments, suggestions, please?

Thnx.

Comment: Do you want to *set-wise union* the inner arrays or *concatenate* them? What would you want to happen to `[ [['a','A']], [['a','A']] ]`?

Comment: [ ['a','A'] ] is desired output in that case

Comment: i wanted set wise union. i did a silly by putting v|k instead of k|v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.inject([]){|k,v| k|v}
```

Comment: Or, shorter, `a.inject(&:|)` (lol, a confused smiley with a funny hat!)

Comment: yes. i just tried this, before getting your answer. my bad. this was a silly question.

Comment: @MladenJablanović, can you please explain(in brief) how this a.inject(&:|) works. I know that, you use '&' as short for each element.

Comment: Very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003257/how-does-1-4-inject-work-in-ruby with lots of links in there as well.

Comment: @MladenJablanović- a.inject(:|) will also be fine. no need for & in this case. cheers...

Answer (score 5):

`array.flatten` takes a parameter:

```
a.flatten(1) #[["a", "A"], ["b", "B"], ["c", "C"], ["d", "D"], ["e", "E"], ["f", "F"]]
```

Comment: wow! thats nice solution. i have been trying flatten without parameter, which was giving ["a", "A", "b", "B", "c", "C", "d", "D", "e", "E", "f", "F"]
can you please explain the need for parameter here. thnx

Comment: The parameter specifies how much levels you want to flatten. The default is 'all'; in this case just 1 level is sufficient.