# Rails How to get value from 'group' query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm studying Redmine application by Rails.

I make the query as below:

```
re = Issue.select("sum(id) as test_total").group("tracker_id")
```

But I can not get the 'total_price' value. Here's the result of 're.inspect'

```
[#<Issue >, #<Issue >, #<Issue >]
```

It's only array of empty Issue objects.

Then I see the query in log:

```
SELECT sum(id) as test_total FROM "issues" GROUP BY tracker_id
```

If I run this query by database console, the result is:

```
| test_total |
-------------
|     1      |
-------------
|     2      |
-------------
|     3      |
-------------
```

It's 3 rows of result.

The previous 're' has 3 elements but each element is one empty Issue object.

How can I get 'total_price' from 're'?

Thank you.

Comment: I know I've answered this before but I can't find the duplicate right now. Summary: `inspect` shows you the column values that match the underlying table's schema. The table has no `test_total` so it won't show up in `inspect` output. The objects in `re` will have `test_total` methods though and they'll be created via `method_missing`. So you can say `re.map(&:test_total)` and it will work.

Comment: @muistooshort Your answer is more perfect. I am deleting mine, could you add your answer. I answered, as I know this behavior in Rails. But never tried to see source code..

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I'd rather find the duplicate to avoid cluttering the site.

Comment: @muistooshort Okay.. I will wait to see that then.

Comment: Apologies @muistooshort, I didn't see your comment before answering.

Comment: I can't find the duplicate I'm thinking off, that one is close enough though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:

```
re.all.map &:attributes
```

will show you the attributes you have available.

Secondly, why are you looking for 'total_price' when your query creates a sum called 'test_total'?

```
re.first.test_total
```

should do it.

If you want the total of the totals:

```
re.all.map(&:test_total).inject(:+)
```

'map' creates a new array from an old one by processing a block. &:test_total is short-hand for `{ |i| i.test_total }`, creating an array of test_total values. Inject performs an operation on a variable that's passed through to each iteration of the loop. In this case it's calling the '+' method on the passed variable and each array member. For a deeper explanation, see here:

[How does "(1..4).inject(&:+)" work in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003257/how-does-1-4-inject-work-in-ruby)