# What does following statement &:property?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

I know,
that i can sort an array of objects by specific field with following code:

```
articles = articles.sort_by(&:date)
```

What actually does this magical statement ?

&:date

What is going here ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of no less than 12 other questions that have already been asked and answered here on StackOverflow: [Understanding \[ClassOne, ClassTwo\].each\(&:my_method\)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/99318/), [What does `map(&:name)` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1217088/), [What exactly is is this in ruby: `&:capitalize`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1792683/), [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1961030/), [Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2096975/), …

Comment: … [What is this `&:last` Ruby Construct Called?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2211751/), [What do you call the `&:` operator in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2259775/), [What does `map(&:name)` do in this Ruby code?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2388337/), [What are `:+` and `&+` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2697024/), [`&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3888044/), [Ruby Proc Syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4512587/), [How does “`(1..4).inject(&:+)`” work in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5003257/).

Comment: Let's see if we can close all those other questions as well!

Comment: 12 duplicates, 12 votes in a day ...  I think this is the beginning of a beautiful friendship.