# What does the `&` mean in the following ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators

In the following ruby example, what does the `&` represent? Is it along the line of `+=` in a loop?

```
payments.sum(&:price)
```

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

&:price is shorthand for "use the #price method on every member of the collection".

Unary "&", when passed as an argument into a method tells Ruby "take this and turn it into a Proc". The #to_proc method on a symbol will #send that symbol to the receiving object, which invokes the corresponding method by that name.

Comment: Specifically, it's equivalent to `payments.sum { |payment| payment.price }`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong,  but neither the `&` or the `:` have anything to do with "for every member of the collection". That's a property of the `sum` method.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with `+=`. The unary `&` operator, when used in a method call, turns the given Proc object into a block. If the operand is not a Proc (as in this case where it is a symbol), first `to_proc` is called on it and then the resulting Proc object is turned into a block.

Answer (score 1):

"If the last argument to a method is preceded by an ampersand, Ruby assumes that it is a Proc object. It removes it from the parameter list, converts the Proc object into a block, and associates it with the method."

From [Programming Ruby:  The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby)

Read more about it [in this article](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/01/ruby-invoking-method-with.html).

Comment: Thanks, The second article in your answer was very useful.

Answer (score -1):

I'm hardly a Ruby expert, but as I recall, it means much the same as it would in C/C++, where it is the address-of operator. In other words, the method `price` *itself* is passed as an argument to `sum`, instead of `price` being called, and the result being passed to `sum`

Comment: This is a surprisingly good guess but it's not quite right. mattt's answer is right.

Comment: Not quite right in terms of what goes on under the hood, but the outcome, from the users point of view is very similar. For someone familiar with C or C++, it's a reasonable mental model of "what it means"