# using sort_by in ruby (for rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've built a custom array of users like such:

```
[["user1",432],["user1",53],["user9",58],["user5",75],["user3",62]]
```

I want to sort them by the 2n'd value in each array, from largest to smallest. I have a feeling using sort or sort_by for arrays is the way to do this, but I'm not really sure how to accomplish it

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## sort_by

If you're interested in `sort_by`, you could destructure your inner arrays

```
array.sort_by { |_, x| x }.reverse
```

or call the index operator

```
array.sort_by { |x| x[1] }.reverse
```

Instead of reversing you could negate values returned from the block.

```
array.sort_by { |_, x| -x }
array.sort_by { |x| -x[1] }
```

Yet another alternative would be to use an [ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby) and `Array#last`.

```
array.sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

## sort

A solution using `sort` could be

```
array.sort { |x, y| y[1] <=> x[1] }
```

Comment: If you're going for completeness then you might want to include `array.sort_by(&:last).reverse`.

Comment: and yet for completeness you should add the simple `array.sort_by { |u, uid| -uid }`. Also, note that it could benefit from using `Enumerable#reverse_each` for a more space-efficient reversing (when a enumerator fits, of course).

Comment: I am facing issues while using sort or sort_by in my presenter and controller. It says undefined method 'sort_by' . Can any one shed light on this?

Comment: sorry this question is not related, can you explain how your first and second solution works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this: `array.sort_by { |a| -a[1] }`

Comment: I've been always puzzle by `sort_by` not having a reverse option.

Comment: nit-picking: unpacking block arguments is considered more idiomatic that accessing them as an array.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution to `sort_by` in reverse (`-` doesn't work in all cases, think sorting by string):

```
class Invertible
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :x

  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def <=> (x)
    x.x <=> @x
  end
end

class Object
  def invertible
    Invertible.new(self)
  end
end

[1, 2, 3].sort_by(&:invertible) #=> [3, 2, 1]
["a", "b", "c"].sort_by(&:invertible) #=> ["c", "b", "a"]
```

It is slower than reverse in simple case, but may work better with complex sorts:

```
objs.sort_by do |obj|  
  [obj.name, obj.date.invertible, obj.score, ...]
end
```