# what is the functionality of "&: " operator in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

I came across a code snippet which had the following

```
a.each_slice(2).map(&:reverse)
```

I do not know the functionality of `&:` operator. How does that work?

Comment: This is a duplicate of no less than 17 other questions that have already been asked and answered here on StackOverflow: [Understanding \[ClassOne, ClassTwo\].each\(&:my_method\)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/99318/), [What does `map(&:name)` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1217088/), [What exactly is `&:capitalize` in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1792683/), [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1961030/), [Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2096975/), …

Comment: … [What is this `&:last` Ruby Construct Called?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2211751/), [What do you call the `&:` operator in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2259775/), [What does `map(&:name)` do in this Ruby code?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2388337/), [What are `:+` and `&+` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2697024/), [`&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3888044/), [Ruby Proc Syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4512587/), [How does “`(1..4).inject(&:+)`” work in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5003257/), …

Comment: … [What does following statement `&:property` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5620411/), [What does the `&` mean in the following ruby syntax?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5952175/), [Why would one use the unary operator on a property in ruby? i.e `&:first`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6289084/), [how does `Array#map` have parameter to do something like this?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6716629/), and [what does `&:` mean in ruby, is it a block mixed with a symbol?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/9188362/).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

There isn't a `&:` operator in Ruby. What you are seeing is the `&` operator applied to a `:symbol`.

In a method argument list, the `&` operator takes its operand, converts it to a `Proc` object if it isn't already (by calling `to_proc` on it) and passes it to the method as if a block had been used.

```
my_proc = Proc.new { puts "foo" }

my_method_call(&my_proc) # is identical to:
my_method_call { puts "foo" }
```

So the question now becomes "What does `Symbol#to_proc` do?", and that's easy to see in [the Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/Symbol/to_proc):

> Turns the symbol into a simple proc, which is especially useful for enumerations. Examples:

```
# The same as people.collect { |p| p.name }
people.collect(&:name)

# The same as people.select { |p| p.manager? }.collect { |p| p.salary }
people.select(&:manager?).collect(&:salary)
```

Comment: @kikito: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc

Comment: @kikito: actually it was first implemented in Rails, but everyone loved it so it made its way into the core.

Comment: Is there a way to pass and argument to the method being called? `salary` for example

Answer (score 41):

By prepending `&` to a symbol you are creating a lambda function that will call method with a name of that symbol on the object you pass into this function. Taking that into account:

```
ar.map(&:reverse)
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
ar.map { |element| element.reverse }
```