# Selecting all current attributes of a model for validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-console

When setting up my models I often find myself having to write out all of its attributes when setting up certain validations. A common example is when I use the `presence` parameter:

`validates :first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, presence: true`

Is there a clever way to select all of its attributes without explicitly writing them all out similar to how you can retrieve them in the rails console?

`User.columns`

And pass it as an argument in the validates method?

```
ALL_ATTRIBUTES = User.columns

validates ALL_ATTRIBUTES, presence: true
```

Trying something like this out I got this error `undefined method 'to_sym'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will NOT encourage you or anyone to do this. Reason being when you run into issues, when an object of your model doesn't get saved and throw errors because of a new column which was added to application after some time in future, and you or new developers will wonder WHY?!?!.

However, if you must do then here you go:

```
validates *self.column_names.map(&:to_sym), presence: true
```

Here, `*` in Ruby is known as [splat operator](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html) and [here's the explanation on &:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429972/645886).

Comment: Thanks for the warning and yes this seems to do the trick. Just a few questions. Why the `*` before self and `&:` before converting the attributes to symbols?

Comment: @CarlEdwards `column_names.map(&:to_sym)` is shorthand for `column_names.map { |column| column.to_sym }`. If you are only calling a method on the attributes, then you can shorten is to use `&:to_sym`. It's syntactic sugar.

Comment: @CarlEdwards: added explanation of your doubts. If an answer helps then please accept it so others can use it for reference. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation and fair warning against using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awful idea. But you can do it this way:

```
attrs = column_names.map { |column| column.to_sym }
validates *attrs, presence: true
```

Why is it a bad idea? Because it's not very clear what is being validated it. It makes debugging hard, and could cause you have strange bugs. If you add a column in the future that does not require presence validation, you will trip up. Also, some things my not require presence. For example, an email field will need a regex validation, which automatically knows that a blank string is invalid. So a presence validator is redundant.

Beware of being *too clever*, as it's sometimes not so clever after all.

Comment: I ended up getting this: `undefined method 'to_sym' for [:id, :name, :position, :visible, :created_at, :updated_at]:Array`