# Ruby find and return objects in an array based on an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

How can you iterate through an array of objects and return the entire object if a certain attribute is correct?

I have the following in my rails app

```
array_of_objects.each { |favor| favor.completed == false }

array_of_objects.each { |favor| favor.completed }
```

but for some reason these two return the same result! I have tried to replace `each` with `collect`, `map`, `keep_if` as well as `!favor.completed` instead of `favor.completed == false` and none of them worked!

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What I want is to return the entire object `favor` if `favor.completed` and if `!favor.completed`

Comment: the `each` method always returns the original array.

Comment: Just to qualify @sugar's comment, when it has a block, [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns its receiver.

Comment: What do you mean by, "return the *entire* object"? Do you mean you want to return an array of those objects from the first array for which a given attribute evaluates `true`? Or evaluates 'false'?

Comment: yes that's what I meant. I don't want to have the attribute returned

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
array_of_objects.select { |favor| favor.completed == false }
```

Will return all the objects that's completed is false.

You can also use `find_all` instead of `select`.

Comment: Are there any non-destructive methods similar to `select`?

Comment: Didn't understand `non-destructive`, sorry.

Comment: `select` changes the original array, I was just wondering if there's a similar specialised method that keeps the original array intact?

Comment: No `select` doesn't change `self`. `select!` does.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. Got confused now.

Answer (score 15):

For first case,

```
array_of_objects.reject(&:completed)
```

For second case,

```
array_of_objects.select(&:completed)
```

Comment: Nicely, done, assuming we both understand the question correctly. btw, I see the wand is no more.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: what does the :& mean?

Comment: @liyicky Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429819/what-is-the-functionality-of-operator-in-ruby

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`Enumerable#find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) to get the all matched objects.

```
array_of_objects.find_all { |favor| favor.completed == false }
```

Comment: both `find` and 'find_all'` are returning nil for me! :( very annoying

Comment: this is the array of objects I'm calling them on `[#<RequestedFavor id: 8, title: "Moving day", description: "Help me move to my new flat please!", user_id: 1, completed: false, created_at: "2016-01-30 18:19:33", updated_at: "2016-01-30 18:19:33", type: "RequestedFavor">, #<OfferedFavor id: 9, title: "Got two hours free", description: "I can spare two hours on Friday", user_id: 1, completed: false, created_at: "2016-01-30 18:19:52", updated_at: "2016-01-30 18:19:52", type: "OfferedFavor">]`

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of ruby, you can use `filter` method

```
array_of_objects.filter { |favor| favor.completed == false }
```

Reference: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/filter

Comment: "Newest" means Ruby from 1.8.6_287 ?? (by [your reference](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/filter))