# Ruby each with object syntatic sugar explanation

Tags: ruby

Why are these not equal?

```
['a'].each_with_object('b'){|x,memo| memo << x}
=> "ba"

['a'].each_with_object('b', &:<<)
=> "b"
```

I thought that the second is just a syntactically sugarized version of the first.

Comment: second code is not same as the first output tells that. But I don't know from where to start the explanations. :) In your second code `memo` is `'b'` and `x` is `'a'`. But that `memo << x` is not happening, and it shouldn't though. And that is why once block is finished `memo` is getting returned, as that is how `each_with_object` works, it returns `memo`

Comment: Could you write the long form equivalent of the second example and submit that as an answer?

Comment: This answer describes how the `&` operator works and might shed some light on why the two are not equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9429972/446681

Comment: You can seem the implementation in C here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc. If you don't know C, like me. You might find this interesting: `['a'].reduce('b', &:<<) #=> "ba"`. If you think about it, with each_with_object, even if the strings did concatenate, you would have "ab" instead of "ba", so the two examples should not be equal anyway.

Comment: @jphager2 “even if the strings did concatenate”—the strings _did concatenate_, see my answer.

Comment: aha so its just because of the order of the args to the proc, and that each_with_object returns the object. Obviously =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Symbol#to_proc` returns a `Proc` instance of arity `-1`:

```
:<<.to_proc.arity
#⇒ -1
```

That said, it will silently accept any number of arguments, then basically call `args.first.method(self).to_proc` and pass the result of the above as codeblock parameter to the caller. That is why `['a'].reduce('b', :<<)` works as you expected: `reduce`’s first block argument is `memo`, and

```
'b'.method(:<<, 'a')
```

returns `"ba"` string.

Your code works the same way:

```
arr = ['a']
arr.each_with_object('b', &:<<)
arr
#⇒ ['ab']
```

You’ve just expected the wrong receiver for `String#<<` method. In this case, the receiver is an array element, since it’s passed to the block *as the first argument*. Look:

```
arr = ['a', 'b']
arr.each_with_object('z', &:<<)
arr
#⇒ ['az', 'bz']
```

`memo` itself stays untouched and returned as a result of call to `each_with_object`. You might even have it `frozen` and the code will still work.

That said, there is no way to achieve the functionality you requested with syntactic sugar using `Symbol#to_proc` and `each_with_object`.

Comment: The old rails implementation of `Symbol#to_proc` was `Proc.new { |*args| args.shift.__send__(self, args) }`

Comment: @jphager2 How is it different from the current implementation and/or the code snippet I provided (save for that my version does not mutate `args` array, what makes no sense taking into account that `args` are all on the stack)?

Comment: The current implementation is written in C and does a lot more, like trying to find the proc in a cache, marking the proc for garbage collection, etc. Actually, I think your implementation has a bug, assuming that you are in the context of a Symbol instance. You will not have access to the args in the method definition of Symbol#to_proc.

Comment: Ah, if you meant the current Rails, implementation, then there isn't one, because Symbol#to_proc is defined now in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object is the first argument passed to `each_with_object`. In the first example, this first object `"b"` is appended with "`a`", which is returned. In the second example, the element of the receiver `"a"` is appended with the first argument `"b"`, but nothing happens to the first argument.