# How to pass &:read as argument to File.open as indicated by Rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have this code

```
File.open(file_name, 'r') { |file| file.read }
```

but Rubocop is warning:

> **Offenses:**
>
> *Style/SymbolProc*: Pass `&:read` as argument to `open` instead of a
>   block.

How do you do this?

Comment: You would like to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429972/10522579

Comment: You could just do `File.read(file_name)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just created a file named "t.txt" that contains "Hello, World\n". We can read that as follows.

```
File.open('t.txt', 'r', &:read)
  #=> "Hello, World\n"
```

Incidentally, as the default of the second argument is `'r'`, it suffices to write:

```
File.open('t.txt', &:read)
```

Here's another example:

```
"This is A Test".gsub('i', &:upcase)
  #=> "ThIs Is A Test"
```

In other words, include the proc (e.g., `&:read`) as the last argument.

Answer (score 3):

`File.open(file_name, 'r', &:read)`

Rubocop wants you to use the ['symbol to proc'](https://skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/#thesymboltoproctrick) feature in Ruby instead of defining a complete block.  This is purely stylistic, and doesn't affect the code execution. You can find it in the [Rubocop style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide/tree/d721dd275ce5e63ab563891f69439d97c9437ff1#single-action-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the offense in RuboCop's docs, e.g. [Style/SymbolProc](https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/cops_style/#stylesymbolproc) – it usually shows a "bad" and a "good" example:

```
# bad
something.map { |s| s.upcase }

# good
something.map(&:upcase)
```

If this doesn't help, you can have RuboCop [auto-correct](https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/auto_correct/) the offense (for cops supporting auto-correction like this one).

Given a file `test.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

File.open(file_name, 'r') { |file| file.read }
```

Run `rubocop -a`: (the actual output depends on your config)

```
$ rubocop -a test.rb
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

test.rb:3:27: C: [Corrected] Style/SymbolProc: Pass &:read as an argument to open instead of a block.
File.open(file_name, 'r') { |file| file.read }
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected, 1 offense corrected
```

And `test.rb` will become:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

File.open(file_name, 'r', &:read)
```