# Rails pluck with an ampersand (pluck(&:something)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I accidentally wrote `pluck(&:id)` instead of `pluck(:id)` and I got some unusual results and I'm curious what is actually happening. What came back looks like an array of all the values (no keys) from the object I was `pluck`ing from.

The results looked like this:

```sh
=> [[5874, "Vancouver", Wed, 01 Mar 2023, Wed, 01 Mar 2023, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, true, false, false, 212388, 212388, nil, false, nil, false, nil, false, "Vancouver, BC", true, false, "23VBCCIOIC5874", false, nil, nil]]
```

I then noticed that I could put anything after the `&` and it didn't matter. Such as `pluck(&:ham_sandwich)` would give the same results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the functionality of "&: " operator in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429972/895789)

Comment: `pluck` method checks if the passed argument matches any column name or not, if yes then it returns the value of that column, and if no it returns the value of all columns. `:id` matches the `id` column and `&:id` matches none so that is why you are getting this output. Try calling only `pluck` without any arguments it would return all the columns. So there is no role of `&` here.