# Using symbols to access instance variables?

Tags: ruby, block, symbols, proc

Apparently, Ruby can make a code block returning an instance variable's value with a symbol. Consider:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :fn
end

def give(n,&b)
    i=0
    while(i<n)
       aa = Person.new
       aa.fn = "name #{i}"
       i=i+1
       puts b.call(aa)
    end
end
```

Now, both `give(5, &:fn)` and `give(5) {|x| x.fn}` give

```
name 0
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
=> nil
```

But what does `&:fn` really mean? I know the ampersand can convert a Proc to a block such as

```
bb = Proc.new {|x| x.fn}
give(5, &bb)
```

So what does the symbol `:fn` mean? Where can I see a documentation of its use like this? Can we use a symbol to access the instance variable, like say `person:new` or `person[:new]`?

Comment: `person[:new]` would be used for accessing a hash where the key is a symbol

Comment: @KassymDorsel, thanks. I know the case for hashes, but here it is an object of a class, and the symbol in '&:fn` accesses the instance variable.

Comment: ampersand will convert object to `Proc` actually, and `:fn` means just symbol, `&:fn` is equivalent to `&(:fn.to_proc)`

Comment: @VictorMoroz, you mean `&:fn` is equivalent to `:fn.to_proc`?

Comment: you can pass lambda to your function like this `give(5, &lambda{ |x| x.fn })`, ampersand is a part of Ruby syntax for passing `Proc` object to a method (or any other object if it has `to_proc` method).

Comment: http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: @highBandWidth "and the symbol in '&:fn` accesses the instance variable. " No, no, it calls the `fn` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. The statment

```
attr_accessor :fn
```

Doesn't define some sort of special instance variable thing. It declares two methods of (approximately) this form:

```
def fn
  @fn
end
def fn=(v)
  @fn=v
end
```

The Ruby "syntax" `&:fn` is a symbol that the operator `&` tries to convert to a proc. And, guess what? `Symbol` implements `to_proc`. Guess that that looks like:

```
def to_proc
  Proc.new {|obj| obj.__send__(self)}
end
```

That captures `self`, which is the symbol `:fn`, which, on invocation, tells `obj` to execute the method `fn`, which returns the value of the instance variable.

EDIT: Answering the second part of the question, no and yes. With the syntax you say, no. But you can call a method from a symbol with `BasicObject#__send__` and you can do the same for **not `attr_accessor`** instance variables with `Object#instance_variable_get`.