# What is the &: of &:aFunction doing?

Tags: ruby, symbols, proc

I'm reviewing someone's ruby code and in it they've written something similar to:

```
class Example
  attr_reader :val
  def initialize(val)
    @val = val
  end
end

def trigger
  puts self.val
end

anArray = [Example.new(10), Example.new(21)]
anArray.each(&:trigger)
```

The `:trigger` means the symbol is taken and the `&` transforms it into a `proc`?

If that's correct, is there any way of passing variables into trigger apart from using `self.`?

This is related but never answered:  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/198284#863450

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGrimm, that adds some more depth to it.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way of passing variables into trigger

No.

You're invoking `Symbol#to_proc` which does not allow you to specify any arguments. This is a convenient bit of sugar Ruby provides specifically for invoking a method with no arguments.

If you want arguments, you'll have to use the full block syntax:

```
anArray.each do |i|
  i.trigger(arguments...)
end
```

Comment: I couldn't find this in the docs, how did you learn this / could I have learnt this by myself?  Thanks.

Comment: Google "symbol to_proc". The second link is to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc).

Comment: Nice, I was only trying `&:` and thus not finding anything, including the `(&:to_s)` in that documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`Symbol#to_proc` is a shortcut for calling methods without parameters. If you need to pass parameters, use full form.

```
[100, 200, 300].map(&:to_s) # => ["100", "200", "300"]
[100, 200, 300].map {|i| i.to_s(16) } # => ["64", "c8", "12c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you need:

```
def trigger(ex)
  puts ex.val
end

anArray = [Example.new(10), Example.new(21)]
anArray.each(&method(:trigger))
# 10
# 21
```