# reference to a method?

Tags: ruby

I would like to replace this:

```
[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].map {|p| p.first}
```

with a more terse version by sending a reference to Array's `first` method to `map`, but it gives me errors:

```
[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].map Array.method(:first)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']].map(&:first)
```

Comment: It's called the "pretzel colon" and is a shorthand for `Symbol#to_proc`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby