# reference to a method on an object

Tags: ruby

I have asked a similar question earlier: [reference to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856978/reference-to-a-method)

but now I am trying to figure out how to do this with this code:

```
arr0 = [1,2,3]
arr1 = [2,3,4,5]
arr1.reject! {|x|
    arr0.include? x
}
```

apparently `{|x| arr0.include? x}` can be simplified to just `arr0.include?`. But I do not know how to get this method reference.

EDIT: I am not interested in how to subtract arrays in Ruby using a simpler syntax. I am looking for a way to get a reference to a method.

Comment: why not just do `arr1 - arr0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Object in Ruby has a `method` method:

```
m = [1,2,3].method(:include?) #reference to the include? method of this array.
p m.call(1) #call the method with an argument ; => true
```

Answer (score 6):

```
arr1.reject!(&arr0.method(:include?))
```

Comment: @steenslag: The ampersand in a *parameter list* means "wrap this block in a `Proc`". The ampersand in an *argument list* means "unwrap this `Proc` into a block (and call `to_proc` on it first, if it isn't already a block)". `Method` implements `to_proc`, just like `Symbol` does, so, it works exactly the same way as it does with `Symbol`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
arr1 - arr0
```

and you can't do that with a pretzel colon, because you have an argument.

Comment: yes, I can do that with this syntax. my question is how to get the method in the sample code that I posted.

Comment: arr1 -= arr0 since reject! modifies the receiver.

Comment: :) thanks. I did not mean to say that I want to use pretzel column necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr0 = [1,2,3]
arr1 = [2,3,4,5]

m = arr0.method(:include?)
arr1.reject!(&m) #=> [4, 5]
```