# How to perform function to subarray inside ruby multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in ruby like this one:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

How do I add "1" to each element.  For instance, I want to end up with something like this:

```
a = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a slightly more clever one liner but this is fairly clear.

```
a.map { |ar| ar.map { |e| e + 1 } }
```

Comment: `a.map { |ar| ar.map(&:next) }` to avoid opening two blocks :)

Comment: Thanks, I had been sitting in irb for a few minutes trying to figure it out. Is it possible to do it without declaring `|ar|`?

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, but we'd need to declare a method on `Array` that takes each elements and adds 1 to them since there's nothing like that in the standard library

Comment: Is it not possible to do something like `a.map(&:map)` and somehow pass `&next` to that?

Comment: But I added an answer to declare a method that allows us to use only one `map` when we do the call, the other being hidden in the method of course

Comment: Thanks Anthony. What is the `&:` form called? It looks like a block but I don't know what its called when you pass it like that.

Comment: I didn't know how it's called until I read a comment here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby. Apparently code `pretzel colon` ... also there's a full explanation of how the magick works in it, a good read

Comment: @Sunny. Why `+=` instead of `+`?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun :

```
class Array
  def increment
    map(&:next)
  end
end

#Tada!
a.map(&:increment)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.map { |xs| xs.map(&:succ) }
#=> [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```