# Ruby capitalize every word first letter

Tags: ruby, string

I need to make the first character of every word uppercase, and make the rest lowercase...

```
manufacturer.MFA_BRAND.first.upcase
```

is only setting the first letter uppercase, but I need this:

```
ALFA ROMEO => Alfa Romeo
AUDI => Audi
BMW => Bmw
ONETWO THREE FOUR => Onetwo Three Four
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

try this:

```
puts 'one TWO three foUR'.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')

#=> One Two Three Four
```

or

```
puts 'one TWO three foUR'.split.map(&:capitalize)*' '
```

Comment: `split` will split on space by default, so you can make it even shorter: `'one TWO three foUR'.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')`

Comment: @waltee Could you possibly explain the `.map(&:capitalize)` or at least point to where in the doc you found it? I can't find any reference to that. Also, what is the deal with the `*' '` at the end of the second code snippet?

Comment: @macsplean the `&:method` syntax in `map` is a [concise way to call a method on each item in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-ampersand-colon-pretzel-colon-mean-in-ruby). You can then call `join` to turn that array into a string. The `* ' '` is an [alternative way to call join](http://brettu.com/ruby-ruby-tips-236-alternative-arrayjoin-syntax/). You can think of it as multiplying the items in the array together to create a string.

Answer (score 346):

In Rails:

```
"kirk douglas".titleize => "Kirk Douglas"
#this also works for 'kirk_douglas'
```

w/o Rails:

```
"kirk douglas".split(/ |\_/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")

#OBJECT IT OUT
def titleize(str)
  str.split(/ |\_/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
end

#OR MONKEY PATCH IT
class String  
  def titleize
    self.split(/ |\_/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  end
end
```

w/o Rails (load rails's ActiveSupport to patch #titleize method to `String`)

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
"kirk douglas".titleize #=> "Kirk Douglas"
```

### (some) string use cases handled by #titleize

- "kirk douglas"
- "kirk_douglas"
- "kirk-douglas"
- "kirkDouglas"
- "KirkDouglas"

### #titleize gotchas

Rails's `titleize` will convert things like dashes and underscores into spaces and can produce other unexpected results, especially with case-sensitive situations as pointed out by @JamesMcMahon:

```
"hEy lOok".titleize #=> "H Ey Lo Ok"
```

because it is meant to handle camel-cased code like:

```
"kirkDouglas".titleize #=> "Kirk Douglas"
```

To deal with this edge case you could clean your string with `#downcase` first before running #titleize. Of course if you do that you will wipe out any camelCased word separations:

```
"kirkDouglas".downcase.titleize #=> "Kirkdouglas"
```

Comment: There is also a gem [titleize](https://github.com/granth/titleize) that works nicely.

Comment: Titleize isn't as simple as it looks, for instance 'hEy LoOK' becomes 'H Ey Lo Ok'

Comment: HUGE GOTCHA, titleize will remove certain characters completely, such as the dash ( - ). "who? - me".titleize => "Who?   Me"

Comment: @pixelearth for me its converting all the dashes to individual spaces.

Answer (score 38):

`"hello world".titleize` which should output "Hello World".

Comment: This outputs `"One Two Three Fo Ur"` which is different than the desired output in this case, but may be desired in others.

Comment: This isn't a Ruby method; it's an ActiveSupport (Rails) method introduced in v2.2.1

Answer (score 25):

Another option is to use a regex and gsub, which takes a block:

```
'one TWO three foUR'.gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize)
```

Comment: This one preserves inter-word dashes etc.

Comment: `.gsub(/\b\w/, &:capitalize)` preserves intended capitalization within words, e.g. "Jane mcCollins"

Comment: Using `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\w` makes it unicode aware.

Answer (score 5):

Look into the String#capitalize method.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize

Comment: String#capitalize downcases the rest of the string after the first letter. For names like "McGee", that is an undesired result, but it is partly useful in this case.

Answer (score 5):

```
"hello world".split.each{|i| i.capitalize!}.join(' ')
```

Comment: there's no reason to use a bang (!) operator if you're not working with a variable

Comment: @boulder_ruby It's not true that *"there's no reason to use a bang operator if you're not working with a variable."* The return value of each iteration of the `each` block is being discarded. The `!` is modifying the strings produced by `split` in-place. Without the `!`, `capitalize` would be creating one new capitalized string per iteration, and then immediately discarding it. The final result would be `"hello world"`, just the same as the original string. With the `!`, each string in the `split`'d array is being changed, and therefore the result of `each` is an array of capitalized strings.

Comment: Yeah you're just supposed to use `map`. Interesting hack though. Points

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in an array you can simply put this:

array_name.map(&:capitalize)

Answer (score 1):

I used this for a similar problem:

```
'catherine mc-nulty joséphina'.capitalize.gsub(/(\s+\w)/) { |stuff| stuff.upcase }
```

This handles the following weird cases I saw trying the previous answers:

- non-word characters like -
- accented characters common in names like é
- capital characters in the middle of the string