# Capitalize the first letter of each word - Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my code and I'm not sure why this doesn't return the expected result: `A Bunny Hops`

```
text= "a bunny hops"
final = text.split.each{|i| i.capitalize}.join(' ')
puts final
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby capitalize every word first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520162/ruby-capitalize-every-word-first-letter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do as below using [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map) :

```
 text.split.map { |i| i.capitalize }.join(' ')
```

Corrected and short code :

```
text= "a bunny hops"
final = text.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
puts final
# >> A Bunny Hops
```

Why didn't your one worked :

Because [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each) method returns the receiver itself on which it has been called :

```
text= "a bunny hops"
text.split.each(&:capitalize) # => ["a", "bunny", "hops"]
```

But `Array#map` returns a new array

```
text.split.map(&:capitalize) # => ["A", "Bunny", "Hops"]
```

I would do it as below using [`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
text= "a bunny hops"
text.gsub(/[A-Za-z']+/,&:capitalize) # => "A Bunny Hops"
```

Note: *The pattern I used here with `#gsub`, is not the trivial one. I did it as per the string have been given in the post itself. You need to change it as per the text string samples you will be having. But the above is a way to do such things with short code and more Rubyish way.*

Comment: Your last one would transform `can't` into `Can'T`

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, any more improvement?

Answer (score 2):

instead of splitting the string into an array, and then joining it back together, just use regular expressions:

```
text = "a bunny hops"
final = text.gsub(/\b(?<!['’`])[a-z]/) { $&.capitalize }
puts final
```

full disclosure, this how the Ruby on Rails `titleize` method works. [View Source.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dbe6a8b03b78c0729a39cc849ca8b79752c65235/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L134)

Comment: Very nice to know this method exists in Rails. I know that the question specifically asks for Ruby but considering the Ruby user base is often synonymous with Rails -- I vote for this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking your existing code, just add ! next to capitalize:

```
final = text.split.each{|i| i.capitalize!}.join(' ')
```

or replace 'each' with 'map':

```
final = text.split.map{|i| i.capitalize}.join(' ')
```

and your goal is accomplished :)