# Capitalize a final first and last name in my program

Tags: ruby

I am trying to ask the user for a name so we can create a fake name.

Fake name will:

- Swap the first and last name
- Change all the vowels (a,e,i,o,u) to next vowel, So 'a' would become 'e','u' would become 'a'
- Change all the consonants to (besides the vowels) to the next consonant in the alphabet, So 'd' would become 'f', 'n' would become 'p'

I am unable to get the first and last name capitalized at the end of the program. Any advice on how to do this?

I am also trying to Use a data structure to store the fake names as they are entered. When the user exits the program, iterate through the data structure and print all of the data the user entered. A sentence like "Vussit Gimodoe is actually Felicia Torres" or "Felicia Torres is also known as Vussit Gimodoe

```
# ---- Swap First and Last Name ----

def name_swap(name)
  name.split.reverse.join(' ')
end

# ---- Change all the vowels ----

def vowel_change(name)
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  name = name.downcase.split('')
  new_name = name.map do |vow|
    if vowels.include?(vow)
       vowels.rotate(1)[vowels.index(vow)]
     elsif vowels == 'u'
      vowels.replace('a')
     else
      vow
     end
   end
  new_name.join
end

# ---- Change the constant ----

def constant_change(name)
  constants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
  name = name.downcase.split('')
  new_name = name.map do |letter|
    if constants.include?(letter)
       constants.rotate(1)[constants.index(letter)]
     elsif constants == 'z'
        constants.replace('b')
     else
      letter
     end
   end
     new_name.join.capitalize!
end


# ---- User Interface and Data Storage----
valid_input = false
agents ={}
user_input = ""
secret_name = ""

until valid_input
  puts "Hello Secret Agent, to begin please enter the name you would like to change. When you are finished, type 'quit' !"
  user_input = gets.chomp.downcase
    if user_input == "quit"
       puts "Thank You!"
       valid_input = true
     else
      secret_name = name_swap(vowel_change(constant_change(user_input)))
       puts "Your secret name is #{secret_name} "
      end
      agents[user_input] = secret_name
    end


agents.each do |name, scramble|
  puts"#{name} is also known #{scramble}"
end
```

The problem is when I return the final agent name the name is lower case and I need both the first name and last name capitalized. It is also taking quit to exit the until loop as a name.

Comment: Tip: You can do things like `vow.match(/[aeiou]/)` or `vowels = 'aeiou'.chars.to_a` to either use a regular expression for quick matching, or to quickly make an array.

Comment: @tadman i do not understand?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear (it doesn't describe in what way the code does not work), and also broad (there's something about capitalization, and also something about using a data structure).  I didn't vote to close it, because you are taking the effort to make a good question (thank you!), but the question does need improvement.

Comment: Please boil you question down to *one* question, with the smallest amount of code that reproduces your issue. Part of the requirements of asking a question here is that you should have already done enough debugging to isolate your problem and be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21

You could do this before you print the secret name:

```
output = output.split.each { |name| name.capitalize! }.join(' ')
```

and the same for the original name:

```
original_name = original_name.split.each { |name| name.capitalize! }.join(' ')
```

Examples from Ruby docs:

```
a = "hello"
a.capitalize!   #=> "Hello"
a               #=> "Hello"
a.capitalize!   #=> nil
```

Or use Rails' `titleize` method if you are using Rails.

http://apidock.com/rails/String/titleize

Comment: still does not work

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. That should work now.

Comment: rb:62: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting keyword_end
...ch do |name| name.capitalize! }.join(' ')

Comment: Fixed AGAIN, sorry about that.

Comment: I cleaned up my code and added a little more context on what I am trying to do. I don't understand why I cant do it :( sorry but i am new to coding

Comment: I actually did this assignment so I know exactly what you're trying to do! But no problem! Is capitalization the only problem you're having?

Comment: yes. and when i print the final hash, keys and values it prints out "quit' as the key and whatever was the last user input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125763/discussion-between-sg17-and-bralley).

Answer (score 0):

In rails, you have a method called `titleize`

that said, give this a try

```
output = name_swap(vowel_change(constant_change(original_name))).titleize
original_name = original_name.titleize
```

Reference Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005638/2398387

Comment: it did not work. I need the User Interface to return a first letter capitalization for the first and last name. so when the program gives -  puts "#{output} is also known as #{original_name}" both names have that capitalization

Comment: updated. Does this answer your issue?

Comment: This isn't a Rails question. `titleize` will not be available.

Comment: The original question was tagged with ruby-rails