# Join values from ruby array but keep their type

Tags: ruby

I've got array like this :

```
a = [27624,
     22,
     33,
     "ema",
     "test",
     11,
     nil]
```

When I do `a.join(',')` I get one bing string with values joined. How can I get the same effect but only for my strings to retain their type. Output should look like this :

```
"27624, 22, 33, 'ema', 'test', 11"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.map{|e| e.is_a?(String) ? "'#{e}'" : e}.join(',')
```

Alternatively: (this may not always have the desired effect - particularly for `nil`, as well as some other types you haven't included here)

```
a.map(&:inspect).join(',')
```

Comment: yes that second part totally worked and looks elegant. Can you elaborate on the `a.map(&:inspect)` part. I mean I know about .map{|block| block} but what about `&:inspect`, what is that. Is there a link where I can read about it?

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow ['What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: I think you need compact before join.