# How to combine three map functions into one in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to rewrite these three functions in a single one:

```
def self.net_amount_by_year(year)
  year(year).map(&:net_amount).sum
end

def self.taxable_amount_by_year(year)
  year(year).map(&:taxable_amount).sum
end

def self.gross_amount_by_year(year)
  year(year).map(&:gross_amount).sum
end
```

Can anybody help?

This is what I've got so far:

```
def self.amount_by_year(type_of_amount, year)
  year(year).map(&type_of_amount.to_sym).sum
end
```

The `&type_of_amount` bit doesn't work of course. And I wonder how to do that.

Thanks for any help.

P.S.: By the way, I don't even know what the `&` is for. Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def self.amount_by_year(type_of_amount, year)
  year(year).map{|y| y.send(type_of_amount)}.sum
end
```

In fact, you should just be able to do this:

```
def self.amount_by_year(type_of_amount, year)
  year(year).sum{|y| y.send(type_of_amount)}
end
```

References:
[Ruby send method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send)
[Rails sum method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum)

Comment: By the way, the & in map is shorthand for referencing an attribute or method on the objects (in lieu of using a block, as I did in my answer above). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-ampersand-colon-pretzel-colon-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Depending upon usage, for safety you might add a check to make sure `type_of_amount` matches one of your 3 methods. You wouldn't want someone to call `amount_by_year(:delete, 2013)`

Comment: Kyle is absolutely correct that you should whitelist your passed attribute/method in some way. Although my answer satisfies your question, I would be careful in designing an application in this fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work as is if you give it a symbol (`to_sym` is redundant).

```
def self.amount_by_year(type_of_amount, year)
  year(year).map(&type_of_amount).sum
end
```

`type_of_amount` to be passed should be either `:net_amount`, `:taxable_amount`, or `:gross_amount`.

If you want to compact the arguments, you can even do:

```
def self.amount_by_year(type, year)
  year(year).map(&:"#{type}_amount").sum
end
```

and pass to `type` either `:net`, `:taxable`, or `:gross`.

In fact, you can do:

```
def self.amount_by_year(type, year)
  year(year).sum(&:"#{type}_amount")
end
```

Comment: This is also very good. Thank you! I still wonder what is best here, `.map(..).sum` or using a block as Carlos suggested.

Comment: You can combine them to make it even shorter. See my addition.