# Group Rails query into arrays by attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have these rows: (represented as JSON):

```
[
  { name: "Bob", age: 10 },
  { name: "Carl", age: 15 },
  { name: "Alice", age: 10 },
  { name: "Derek", age: 20 }
]
```

How can I, in Rails, group these by `age`? For example, I want something like this:

```
[
  { age: 10, objects: [
    { name: "Bob", age: 10 },
    { name: "Alice", age: 10 }
  ] },
  { age: 15, objects: [
    { name: "Carl", age: 15 }
  ] },
  { age: 20, objects: [
    { name: "Derek", age: 20 }
  ] },
]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Got it!

```
People.all.group_by(&:age)
```

Comment: What is the ampersand for?

Comment: it's a shortcut for turning the `:age` into a proc, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 10):

If you're actually dealing with JSON:

```
people.group_by{|p| p['age'] }
```

If you're dealing with ActiveRecord models:

```
People.group('id, age')
```

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) there's additional documentation on grouping with ActiveRecord.

Comment: I like the one with the block! Unfortunately I named an association the same way as a column in my PG view and Rails was trying to do some "unexpected" magic with that. Luckily I was able to do akin to `people.group_by{|p| p.read_attribute(:age) }`.