# Skipping a value on enumerable#map if the code block evaluates to false

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Is there a way to refactor this method using map?  (this intention of this method is to return an array of prime numbers between 1 and the max parameter)

```
def primes(max)
  prime_arr = []
   (1..max).each {|i| prime_arr << i if is_prime?(i)}
  prime_arr
end
```

is_prime?(val) returns true or false.

if i change my method to:

```
def primes(max)
 (1..max).map {|i| i if is_prime?(i)}
end
```

The returned array has a nil value when the code blocks fails.

```
p primes(5)
#=> [1, 2, 3, nil, 5]
```

I know what I have works, but i'd rather not declare the array and return the array specifically if there's a better way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.reject` (or [`Enumerable.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)) are the correct methods to *filter* the sequence.

These *filter* methods only looks at the *truthy-ness* of the returned value and thus while returning `i` in this case "works" (as `i` is always a truthy value), the returned value is actually *discarded* (unlike `map`) so the predicate should look more like:

```
c.reject {|i| !is_prime?(i)}

# or (inverting the double negative)
c.select {|i| is_prime?(i)}

# or (with &:)
c.select(&:is_prime?)
```

(See [`&:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-ampersand-colon-pretzel-colon-mean-in-ruby) for the magic behind the latter case.)

Also, since this is dealing with finding prime numbers, the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) might be a good read.

Comment: Yeah, i realized that seconds after posting the questions :)  reject and select is what i was looking for.

Comment: this was more a question about how to avoid the nils on a map, inject, etc. (i'm new to ruby), I suppose the most correct way is to include Primes and Primes.each through the max.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'Prime'
MAX = 100
p Prime.each(MAX).to_a      #=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31...
p (1..MAX).select(&:prime?) #=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31...
```

An alternative is to use [grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) if you want to select and transform:

```
primes = ->x{x.prime?} # (new lambda syntax)
p (1..100).grep(primes){|x| x.to_s} #=> ["2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13", "17",...
```

Comment: That grep example is interesting, but really needs to be explored more ([Proc#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) should be mentioned because it's the entire reason why it works; and the lambda can be substituted with the `&:` to-proc approach). I normally just use `select..map..` in a chain.

Comment: Grep uses the case equality operator in order to select items. You can use Regexp or Class names. Just as you mentioned a lambda (or Proc) is called when compared with ===. This comes in very handy when creating case statements or want to refactor logic from complex chain-functions.

Comment: @hirolau - thanks for the info!  I was, actually, asking for select and reject (apparently); i just didn't know it when i asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... i just figured out A way while trying to explain it, but please feel free to show me a better way!

```
def primes(max)
  (1..max).reject {|i| i if ! is_prime?(i)}
end
```