# array with only non duplicate values

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is not a problem, but more of a question if there are other ways to do this:

I have an array:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,4,5,1,4,3]
```

I want this output: `[2,5]`

My code looks like this:

```
arr.select { |e| arr.count(e) == 1}
```

Are there some alternatives to this?

Comment: If you have two question ask them in two separate posts please. Your second question is [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby) by the way.

Comment: Thanks I have deleted the other question.

Comment: @bjhaid OP wants non uniq elements...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
arr.group_by { |e| e }.select { |k, v| v.size.eql? 1 }.keys
 => [2, 5]
```

Comment: Instead of the `collect(&:first)` you could just use `keys`.

Comment: In terms of readability this is definitely not better than what he has already.

Comment: @Mischa the primary problem with the OP's solution is not readability but a the full array scan for each element, O(n^2) performance.

Comment: I have tested both the solutions on benchmark for performance, mine is almost 7 times faster. count method is taking much more time to execute than how much size method is taking.

Comment: @AlokAnand Consider posting the benchmark for a large array.

Comment: k will do in some time.

Comment: a.group_by { |e| e } (here => {1=>[1, 1], 2=>[2], 3=>[3, 3], 4=>[4, 4, 4], 5=>[5]}) will take quite some memory if the elements occur often.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will scan the array once per element which is acceptable for small arrays, but it should not be necessary. By looking at [this blog post](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2013/10/ruby-quick-tip-easily-count-occurrences-of-array-elements/) it is easy to come up with

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,4,5,1,4,3]
counts=Hash.new(0)

arr.each do |el|
  counts[el]+=1
end

counts.select do |key, count|
  count == 1
end.keys
```

which yields the same result but only traverses your array once (at the expense of two additional hashes though (which you can reduce to one by using `select!` if you do not need the `counts` :-).

Comment: Thanks @bjhaid, did not think of that, of course you would go with `select!` in the one liner ;-)

Comment: `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,h| h[x] += 1 }.select { |k,v| v == 1 }.keys` is the one-liner :)

Answer (score 4):

One needs to have a look at the whole array first to decide the uniqueness

```
def one(a)
  o = { }
  a.each do |x|
    v = o[x]
    if v == nil
      o[x] = true
    else
      if v
        o[x] = false
      end
    end
  end
  return o
end
```

and then use this to pick the unique elements

```
def unique(a)
  o = one(a)
  b = [ ]
  o.each do |k, v|
    if v
      b.push(k)
    end
  end
  return b
end
```

Test code

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3 ]
b = unique(a)
puts "unique: #{a} -> #{b}"
```

Output

```
unique: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3] -> [2, 5]
```

*Dedicated to Edsger W. Dijkstra*

> *A modern, competent programmer should not be puzzle-minded, he should not revel in tricks, he should be humble and avoid clever solutions like the plague*

(from [EWD303](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD303.html))

Comment: I updated it after realizing that there is no need to count over 2, thus keeping the counts small, even if we would have high repetitions. Would you be so nice to update that benchmark?