# What does &:to_s mean in b.map(&:to_s)

Tags: ruby

I am novice in ruby and this question may seem silly for you, but I haven't found any reasonable explanation.

for example I have

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and I'd like to make from this array of strings for some reasons

One of the ways is to do like this:

```
str_arr = array.map {|i| i.to_s}
```

at some web resource I've found the following:

```
array.map(&:to_s)
```

this does the same thing. Could someone explain what `&:to_s` means ??

Answer (score 3):

It's syntactic sugar that turns `to_s` into a block that can be passed to `map`, sort of like passing `to_s` as a function object. Basically, it's shorthand for

```
array.map(&:to_s.to_proc)

# Or to see the individual steps:
proc = :to_s.to_proc
array.map(&proc)
```

See also [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby?rq=1).