# Understanding the map(&:age).sum syntax

Tags: ruby

Let's say we have a line of code that sums up all of the `billable_weeks` total hours, it would look something like this:

```
billable_weeks.map(&:total_hours).sum
```

What role does the `&` play in the above code? Couldn't we just write it as `billable_weeks.map(:total_hours).sum`?

Please help clear this up for me!

Comment: Did you search on Stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: I used to search [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22%26%3A%22) ...

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1217088/1407656

Comment: Note: You could just do `billable_weeks.sum(:total_hours)`. This would do the SUM operation in the database, actually, since `billable_weeks` is an Active Relation object still. If it's an array then do `billable_weeks.sum(&:total_hours)` and it'll still sum like you're asking with less processing time required (doesn't have to map to a new array first).

Comment: Actually, `billable_weeks.map(&:total_hours)` is shorthand form of `billable_weeks.collect { |week| week.total_hours }`.