# Rails special symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm new to Rails. I see some special characters.

```
&:frozen?

&:built?
```

The code is

```
[array].reject(&:frozen?)

[array].reject(&:built?)
```

I checked but I didn't see document for that.

What is the meaning? Thank you

Comment: Reject is a kind of iterator and you sent a method ex. frozen? and it is applied to every element in arry. It is syntax sugar.

Comment: Also a duplicate of and is better answered in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby`.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? It seems to present a few additional questions such as what is `reject` for and what do the `built?` and `frozen?` methods do

Comment: Eh, after reading the question again I only sort of agree with myself. I am personally curious what `built?` is for

Comment: @JKillian It's just the pre-existing code that I read.