# Difference between passing ampersand colon vs just colon (a symbol) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my code I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
    scope :matching, -> (column=nil, value=nil) { where("#{column} = ?", value) }
  ...
end
```

Assuming a valid `public_id: a113f534` (not to be confused with an `:id`), when I do:

`User.matching("pubid", "a113f534").pluck(:id)`

It returns:

`[1]`

If I do:

`User.matching("pubid", "a113f534").pluck(&:id)`

It returns:

```
[[1, "emaildata@inmydb.com", "$blahsomehash", "moreRandomDBdata", nil, Wed, 27 Aug 2014 18:55:33 UTC +00:00, Wed, 27 Aug 2014 21:22:17 UTC +00:00]]
```

Why does using ampersand-colon (which I know calls to_proc on the symbol) return an array with my id as well as more database column data, as opposed to when I just pass in the symbol, which returns what I want (just the id)?

I was under the impression that for Ruby > ~2.0.0, passing in the ampersand was optional and equivalent to just passing in the symbol.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was under the impression that for Ruby > ~2.0.0, passing in the ampersand was optional and equivalent to just passing in the symbol.

No, it's not.

```
pluck(&:id)
```

Is a shorthand for

```
pluck { |u| u.id }
```

i.e. you are passing a block. `pluck` however ignores the block, so the above is equivalent to

```
pluck { }
```

or just

```
pluck
```

which returns an array of all column values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! One thing though - if the ampersand is not no longer optional, why does something like `arr.inject(:+)` produce the same results as `arr.inject(&:+)` ?

Comment: @DannyY Look at the [method signatures of #inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) - they can accept just a symbol (like `:+`), or a block (like `&:+`). So it's not that the & is optional, you can just get away with using either.