# Query objects into groups of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have a topic that has many sources (sources belongs to topic). Each source has a `published_date` field. What I want is to query the `topic.sources` and group them into arrays of objects based published_date.

One way to do this call the `topic.sources`, then sort them by `published_date`. Lastly create new array for each date and shove it into the array accordingly.

topic.sources objects  (array):

```
[#<Source id: 12, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-11-13">,
 #<Source id: 9, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-10-21">
 #<Source id: 8, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-10-21">]
```

This should look like this array of arrays:

```
[[#<Source id: 9, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-10-21">
 #<Source id: 8, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-10-21">],
[#<Source id: 12, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-11-13">]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
topic.sources.group_by(&:published_date)
```

You should get a `Hash` which would look something like this:

```
{"2014-10-24" => [#<Source id: 9, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-10-21">
                  #<Source id: 8, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-10-21">],
 "2014-11-13" => [#<Source id: 12, topic_id: 2, published_date: "2014-11-13">]}
```

Comment: well done sir. That was exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain what the `&` does? I previously tried `topic.sources.group_by(:published_date)` but this didn't work.

Comment: The `&:something` is a shorthand for `{ |x| x.something }`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby