# How to "split and group" an array of objects based on one of their properties

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

**Context and Code Examples**

I have an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) with instances of a class called TimesheetEntry.

Here is the constructor for TimesheetEntry:

```
  def initialize(parameters = {})
    @date       = parameters.fetch(:date)
    @project_id = parameters.fetch(:project_id)
    @article_id = parameters.fetch(:article_id)
    @hours      = parameters.fetch(:hours)
    @comment    = parameters.fetch(:comment)
  end
```

I create an array of TimesheetEntry objects with data from a `.csv` file:

```
  timesheet_entries = []
  CSV.parse(source_file, csv_parse_options).each do |row|
    timesheet_entries.push(TimesheetEntry.new(
      :date       => Date.parse(row['Date']),
      :project_id => row['Project'].to_i,
      :article_id => row['Article'].to_i,
      :hours      => row['Hours'].gsub(',', '.').to_f,
      :comment    => row['Comment'].to_s.empty? ? "N/A" : row['Comment']
    ))
  end
```

I also have a [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) of [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) containing two elements, created like this:

```
  all_timesheets = Set.new []
  timesheet_entries.each do |entry|
    all_timesheets << { 'date' => entry.date, 'entries' => [] }
  end
```

Now, I want to populate the Array inside of that Hash with TimesheetEntries.
Each Hash array must contain only TimesheetEntries of one specific date.

I have done that like this:

```
  timesheet_entries.each do |entry|
    all_timesheets.each do |timesheet|
      if entry.date == timesheet['date']
        timesheet['entries'].push entry
      end
    end
  end
```

While this approach gets the job done, it's not very efficient (I'm fairly new to this).

**Question**

What would be a more efficient way of achieving the same end result? In essence, I want to "split" the Array of TimesheetEntry objects, "grouping" objects with the same date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the performance problem by replacing the `Set` with a `Hash`, which is a dictionary-like data structure.

This means that your inner loop `all_timesheets.each do |timesheet| ... if entry.date ...`  will simply be replaced by a more efficient hash lookup: `all_timesheets[entry.date]`.

Also, there's no need to create the keys in advance and *then* populate the date groups. These can both be done in one go:

```
all_timesheets = {}

timesheet_entries.each do |entry|
  all_timesheets[entry.date] ||= []  # create the key if it's not already there
  all_timesheets[entry.date] << entry
end
```

A nice thing about hashes is that you can customize their behavior when a non-existing key is encountered. You can use the [constructor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block to specify what happens in this case. Let's tell our hash to automatically add new keys and initialize them with an empty array. This allows us to drop the `all_timesheets[entry.date] ||= []` line from the above code:

```
all_timesheets = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

timesheet_entries.each do |entry|
  all_timesheets[entry.date] << entry
end
```

There is, however, an even more concise way of achieving this grouping, using the [`Enumerable#group_by` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
all_timesheets = timesheet_entries.group_by { |e| e.date }
```

And, of course, there's a way to make this even more concise, using yet [another trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217114/390819):

```
all_timesheets = timesheet_entries.group_by(&:date)
```

Comment: Thanks! Learned several new things from your answer. I always thought `Set` was quicker than `Hash` or `Array` for filtering out unique items, since they disregard duplicates automatically when you try to add them; I'll need to dig into that. Also, I did not know about `||=` or `group_by`.

Comment: I replaced nearly all of the above code with this one line as you suggested: `all_timesheets = timesheet_entries.group_by(&:date)` and it's much faster, too. Man, I love Ruby. Thanks again for the pointers.