# How does some_array.each(&method(:some_random_method)) actually work in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently saw this in the source code of one of the applications that I was working on and came to know that this is equivalent to:

```
some_array.each { |element| some_random_method(element) }
```

How does this work internally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

```
               VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

From [Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).