# Capitalizing Vowels in a String with Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a method that takes in a string as an argument, replaces each letter with the next letter in the alphabet and then capitalizes every vowel. I have gotten both of those to work individually (the replacing and capitalization), but at this point, I just don't know how to make them work together.

```
def LetterChanges(str)
    new_str = str.downcase.split("")
    new_str.each do |x|
        x.next!
    end
    new_str.to_s.tr!('aeiou','AEIOU')
    return new_str.join("")
end

LetterChanges("abcdef")
```

Comment: What letter follows `"z"`?

Comment: You should use `.chars` instead of `.split("")`

Answer (score 4):

`new_str.to_s` is not stored anywhere. It doesn't affect the original array.

```
return new_str.join("").tr('aeiou', 'AEIOU')
```

This will convert the array back to a string and you can operate on *that* and return it.

Comment: Or just `str.downcase.split('').map(&:next).join.tr('aeiou','AEIOU')`. [Demo](http://repl.it/y3j)

Comment: Thank you much! That makes so much more sense to me now. Also @suslov, what exactly is the &: before the next? I've seen that in sample code, but its been difficult to research what exactly that does. I've seen and used `inject(:*)` before, which seems similar to that. Thanks again. Very clean and elegant solution. :)

Comment: @dwhipple: you are welcome, there is good explanation about `&` shorthand [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1217088/3444240).

Comment: `join("")` is equivalent to `join` (i.e. unless you change `$,`)

Answer (score 1):

That could be resolved with `gsub`.

```
"abcdef".gsub(/./){|char| char.next}.gsub(/[aeiou]/){|vowel| vowel.upcase}
#=> "bcdEfg"
```

so that method could be

```
def letter_changes_gsub(str)
  str.gsub(/./){|char| char.next}.gsub(/[aeiou]/){|vowel| vowel.upcase}
end
```

That is faster and more simple that work with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already showed you how to combine both parts of your code. But there's [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601237/capitalizing-vowels-in-a-string-with-ruby#comment51154613_31601237):  [`String#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-next) is continuing witch `"aa"` after `"z"`:

```
"z".next #=> "aa"
```

You *could* add an `if` statement to handle this case:

```
str.chars.map do |char|
  if char == 'z'
    'a'
  else
    char.next
  end
end.join
```

or:

```
str.chars.map { |char| char == 'z' ? 'a' : char.next }.join
```

But there's a much simpler way: let [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-tr) perform the entire substitution:

```
str.downcase.tr('a-z', 'bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzA')
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
str.downcase.tr('a-z', 'bcdEfghIjk-nOp-tUv-zA')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2.1.0 :012 > 'abcdef'.split('').map(&:next).join.tr('aeiou', 'AEIOU')
 => "bcdEfg"
```

I would not recommend doing this in one line, of course. But to get at your confusion of how these methods might string together, here is one solution that works. When in doubt, use IRB to call each method and watch how Ruby responds. That will help you figure out where your code is breaking down.

In practice, I would break this into multiple methods. It's too many things for one method to do. And also a lot harder to find bugs (and test), as you found out.

```
def rotate(string)
  string.split('').map(&:next).join
end

def capitalize_vowels(string)
  string.tr('aeiou', 'AEIOU')
end
```

Comment: Why do I often see (sic) "you can do that with the following one-liner". That's akin to a waiter serving me a plate of food and then commenting, " Here is your dinner." Does the waiter think I may not realize that I am to eat it, or wants to be clear that it's for me and not for another patron? Aren't some things just plain obvious?

Comment: @CarySwoveland it looks like it's a proviso that you shouldn't really do it as a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def string_thing(string)
    string.downcase.tr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzA')
end
```

`#tr` just will replace each character in the first parameter with the corresponding one in the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the combination of `gsub` and `tr`:

```rb
"abcdef".gsub(/[A-z]/) { |char| char.next }.tr('aeiou', 'AEIOU')
#=> "bcdEfg"
"Fun times!".gsub(/[A-z]/) { |char| char.next }.tr('aeiou', 'AEIOU')
#=> "GvO Ujnft!"
```