# Ruby Convert integer to binary to integer array of set bits

Tags: ruby, binary, xor

Lets say I have an integer 98. 
The binary representation of this string would be:

```
(98).to_s(2) # 1100010
```

Now I want to convert this binary string to an integer array of all the bits that are set. This would give me:

```
[64,32,2]
```

How would I go about this?

**Update:** The conversion of int to int array does not necessarily need to involve String, it is just what I knew. I assume non String operations would also be faster.

> Ruby is amazing seeing all these different ways to handle this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work:

```
i = 98
(0...i.bit_length).map { |n| i[n] << n }.reject(&:zero?)
#=> [2, 32, 64]
```

- [`Fixnum#bit_length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-bit_length) returns the position of the highest "1" bit
- [`Fixnum#[n]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns the integer's *n*th bit, i.e. `0` or `1`
- [`Fixnum#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C) shifts the bit to the left. `1 << n` is equivalent to 2<sup>n</sup>

Step by step:

```
(0...i.bit_length).map { |n| i[n] }
#=> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

(0...i.bit_length).map { |n| i[n] << n }
#=> [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 32, 64]

(0...i.bit_length).map { |n| i[n] << n }.reject(&:zero?)
#=> [2, 32, 64]
```

You might want to `reverse` the result.

In newer versions of Ruby (2.7+) you could also utilize [`filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#filter_map-method) and [`nonzero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Numeric.html#nonzero-3F-method) to remove all `0` values:

```
(0...i.bit_length).filter_map { |n| (i[n] << n).nonzero? }
#=> [2, 32, 64]
```

Comment: It would not only work, but it is much cleaner than going via `String` like other examples so far.

Comment: undefined method `bit_length' for 98:Fixnum  I am not on the latest Ruby version so this does not seem to work 

ruby 2.0.0p353

Comment: I thought so :/ Ruby is amazing! Is there another non-string way without using bit_length?

Comment: @mahatmanich there's a Ruby implementation for `bit_length`:  https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/2.1.0/fixnum/bit_length.rb Otherwise, you could use a fixed value, depending on your numbers.

Comment: Very elegant!. Nice use of `bit_length`, `[]` and `<<`. Best so far, imo. I was looking through `Fixnum` methods for what I now see is `bit_length`. I don't know how I missed it, as there aren't that many. In any event, I'm glad to know of it.

Comment: @mahatmanich a fixed value of `64` would cover all integers up to `2 ** 64`, maybe that's enough. Otherwise, you could use `i.size << 3`

Comment: @Stefan I have never seen &:zero? What does &: do? ```zero?``` is the fixnum method returning true/false, but &: is unclear, some sort of shorthand?

Comment: @Stefan ok I found it :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Such a performing solution. For large Numbers, converting to string and back is MUCH slower. I only need the first step (without `<<` or `reject` and it's even faster than iterating over the array with `result[i += 1] = input % 2 == 1;
    input /= 2;`

Comment: Stefan, upon returning to this question to respond to a comment on my answer I began re-reading your answer. When I got to `map { |n| i[n] << n }.reject(&:zero?)` I thought I might suggested you mention the since-introduced method `filter_map` then saw you'd done that earlier today (and understand why).

Comment: @CarySwoveland what a coincidence :-) I sometimes revise my (old) answers when getting comments and / or votes.

Comment: Me too, often after wondering what I was thinking, but to be fair, sometimes I was just a crazy kid when I wrote my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways:

**#1**

```
s = (98).to_s(2)
sz = s.size-1
s.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) { |(c,i),a| a << 2**(sz-i) if c == '1' }
  # => [64, 32, 2]
```

**#2**

```
n = 2**(98.to_s(2).size-1)
arr = []
while n > 0
  arr << n if 90[n]==1
  n /= 2
end
arr
  #=> [64, 32, 2]
```

Comment: `98.to_s(2).size` is long and slow for `98.bit_length`

Comment: @Cadoiz, are you sure `98.to_s(n)` is slow when `n = 2`? Were I writing `Integer#to_s` I'd first check if the argument were `2` and if so, compute the result by just examining the bits. Similarly, I would expect `2**n` and `n / 2` are computed intelligently.

Comment: Not slow in terms of absolute time, that should be some micro- or even nanoseconds. Slow in relative time, which means slower by a factor. `to_s(n)` does a conversion to base `n`. As the computer already saves the Integer that way, I would expect no conversion here. But it does convert the number to `String` which means that every binary digit gets converted to Char. That's 8 bit at best, you can check with `98.to_s(2).encoding`, as Ruby allows Unicode since 1.9. After that, an additional method `.size()` is called, which should be about as fast as `.bit_length`.

Comment: Fun-Fact: For some reason, `n /= 2` is even faster than `n >>= 1` on my system. My Intuition based on C-ish languages expected the opposite. [Here's more info on Char/String encodings (Unicode) in Ruby](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/05/ruby-ascii-unicode/), the comment above was getting too long.

Comment: Your reply to my comment above makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
(98).to_s(2).reverse.chars.each_with_index.
   map {|x,i| x=="1" ? 2**i : nil }.compact.reverse
```

Phew! Let's break that down:

- First get the binary String as your example `(98).to_s(2)`
- We will need to start 0-index from right hand side, hence `.reverse`
- `.chars.each_with_index` gives us pairs such as `[ '1', 4 ]` for character at bit position
- The `.map` converts "1" characters to their value `2 ** i` (i.e. 2 to the power of current bit position) and "0" to `nil` so it can be removed
- `.compact` to discard the `nil` values that you don't want
- `.reverse` to have descending powers of 2 as your example

Comment: 'The .map converts "1" characters to their value 2 ** i and "0" to nil so it can be removed' 

Can you elaborate on that? what does 2 ** i do?

Comment: It is just exponentiation, i.e. `x ** y` is "x to the power of y".

Comment: Phew! Why is the first reversal needed?

Comment: Because `.to_s` outputs with least-significant digit on the right, and we want to associate that with bit-position 0 when calculating which power of 2 to use. You can also solve that problem by subtracting position in the string off of the length of the string (Cary's first example does that)

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the string, map it to binary code values of each digit, reject zeros. Optionally reverse it again.

```
s.reverse.chars.map.with_index{ |c, i| c.to_i * 2**i }.reject{ |b| b == 0 }.reverse
```

Or you could push the values to array with `each_with_index`

```
a = []
s.reverse.each_with_index do |c, i|
  a.unshift c.to_i * 2**i
end
```

what is probably faster and more readable, but less idiomatic.

Comment: Which version or Ruby library is giving you `.map` on a `String` here? It's not in core Ruby

Comment: Neat, didn't know about `.with_index` modifier.

Comment: String used to mix Enumerable in some versions ago though, and map worked back than.