# Simple Ruby Proc with (&:)

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, symbols

Quick question, I've run across this `select(&:even)` syntax a few times, and I understand it for the most part except for one thing:

The `&` symbol, to me, is what makes the method name, well a method name. I don't understand why a symbol syntax is needed to define even. In a short example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
puts arr.select(&:even?)
```

correctly selects and prints all the even numbers but,

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
puts arr.select(&even?)
```

produces:

`Untitled 3.rb:2:in <main>: undefined method even? for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

Can anyone help me understand the necessity of using a `:` symbol?

Comment: Method names are symbols, so the reference is to the method `:even?`. The operator `&` does two things: it invokes [Symbol#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) on the method name to convert it to a proc (instance of [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html)) and then calls the proc. If you instead had `arr.select(&proc)`, it would just call the proc.

Comment: I cannot parse your sentence `(The & symbol, to me, is) what makes the method name, well a method name`.

Comment: Why would you think it would work without `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in "[What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)", the `&:whatever` syntax converts the `:whatever` method in a proc and passes it to the caller.

```
puts arr.select(&:even?)
```

is equivalent to

```
puts arr.select { |x| x.even? }
```

The reason why `&:whatever` works whereas `&whatever` does not, is because in the latter case the Ruby virtual machine will actually try to evaluate `whatever` and pass the result to `&`, when what you really want is a sort of lazy-evaluation. You want is to pass a method reference/name to `&`, not execute the method itself.

The error you experience is because the following code

```
puts arr.select(&even?)
```

can be read as

1. execute `even?`
2. get the return value and pass it to `&`
3. ... but hey... `even?` is not defined (notice the target is implicit)... crash!