# Confusion over assocation and getting info from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Confusion over trying to get information from Rails Console

I have the following models: `Article` & `Comment`.

For `Article`, it's a `has_many :comments`

For `Comment`, it's `belongs_to :article`

Let's assume they're associated, and functional. They are by the way.

Here's the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160312052519) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "commenter"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"

end
```

These are the routes:

```
  resources :articles do 
    resources :comments 
  end
```

When I run commands like:

`Article.first.comments`

`Comment.first.article`

`Comment.first.article.title`

`Comment.first.article.text`

`Comment.first.commenter`

`Comment.first.body`

They all work.

But when I try to run the reverse on `Articles` like:

`Article.first.comments.commenter`

`Article.first.comments.body`

`Article.all.comments`

They don't work. Why not?

EDIT

This is what I get when I run `Article.first.comments.commenter`

```
Article.first.comments.commenter
  Article Load (23.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  ORDER BY "articles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError:   Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = ?  [["article_id", 1]]
undefined method `commenter' for #<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa32b7e3d00>
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):127
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/aa/dropbox/beginningRails/guideblogagain/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:185:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: How exactly they don't work? You have `nil` or exception?

Comment: @maximf, have edited my post above to show the error it generates.

Comment: Can you show the Comment class? It needs a `belongs_to :commenter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Article.first.comments` is an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` object, which is similar to an array. If you want to get commenter for each comment you can use `map`

```
Article.first.comments.map(&:commenter)
```

Or you can get first comment's commenter:

```
Article.first.comments.first.commenter
```

Same thing with:

```
Article.first.comments.body # Won't work

Article.first.comments.map(&:body) # Returns an array (each comment's body)

Article.all.comments # Won't work

Article.all.map(&:comments) # Returns an array (each article's comments)
```

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer. Can I ask a follow-up question based on the answer that you've provided? `Article.first.comments.map(&:commenter)`, the `(&:commenter)` is a proc, correct? How is it calling the block of the commenter? Sorry if I didn't word the question correctly.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 yep, it is. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1217114/999223

Answer (score 1):

When you run your working example `Article.first.comments`, take a look at the actual return value.  What do you see? The return is an array of objects, right? So say that `Article.first` has 10 `Comments`. When you run your query, ActiveRecord will return you an array of 10 `Comment` objects.

Now let's take a look at one of your non-working examples.

Say, `Article.first.comments.commenter`.  Again we start with `Article.first`, which we know returns us the first `Article` object in our DB.

But the next step is to think about `Article.first.comments`.

We've already convinced ourselves that that's an array of `Comment` objects, right?  And herein lies the problem -- `commenter` is an attribute on a single `Comment` object.

But you don't have a single `Comment` object -- you have an Array of `Comment` objects and `commenter` isn't defined on an Array.

The `Article.first.comments.body` issue is the same. Does that make sense?

One thing you could do, in your console, is the following:

```
Article.first.comments.each do |comment|  
  puts comment.commenter  
end
```

And then you can get at all of your commenter/body values.

Using this line of thinking, I think you'll be able to convince yourself of the issue with `Article.all.comments`, but if not, feel free to comment and we can talk it out.

[Here are the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for Active Record relations, for reference. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for a thoughtful answer in asking me to think it out. I understand now that as `body` and `commenter` goes, they are single items that I was asking over an array which of course wouldn't work. But I do have one question about `Article.all.comments`. Why doesn't that work? I mean `Article.all` works, right? And `comments` is not a single property per se, so ... ?

Comment: Think of `Article.all` as of array (although it's not). You are trying to call method `comments` on the collection, which knows nothing about its members: whether they have `comments` method or not. You need to call `comments` on *the members* of the collection, e.g. iterate through them and use `map`.

Comment: @queserasera, i've upvoted your answer. thank you very much.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 Thanks! I'm glad you were able to make progress! I wasn't sure how much to throw at you, but maximf nailed it. Cheers :)

Comment: @queserasera, no worries. =)