# Instance Methods vs. Class methods For a Helper Class - Ruby, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I am working on a `rake task` which creates new records in local db based on a query submitted to an external db (`MS SQL`). Connection, querying and record creating happens in a helper I created called `ExternalDatabaseConnector`. Rake tasks simply calls methods and operates as `controller` of sort.

My question is whether methods in my helper class (I have `establish_connection`, `execute_query`, `create_hash` and `store_records`) should be called on `self` (i.e. be class methods) or each be called on an instance of my helper?

I am thinking that there will only be one connection and the rake task will only fire once per its schedule, and there is no need to create separate instances of my helper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to customize the state of each instance
(via `initialize` and instance variables), it makes sense to make class methods
instead. If you're going with class methods, you could make your `Class` a 
`Module` and it would have the same effect.

If you're using a purely functional paradigm when programming, you wouldn't
ever use instance methods. Instead, you'd pass all your needed data as
arguments. I'm not recommending this approach because OOP simply makes things
easier in many cases, but for this situation, class methods make sense to me.
Functional programming is useful (methods like `map`, `reduce`, or the [proc shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)),
but I don't see any reason to use it *instead* of OOP.