# What does this combination of chunk and map do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm solving some problems on codewars while learning Ruby. I solved this [one](http://www.codewars.com/kata/unique-in-order/ruby) in a more C++-ish way (I'm still new to Ruby)

Then I came to check the best solution based on upvotes, which is:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable)
  (iterable.is_a?(String) ? iterable.chars : iterable).chunk { |x| x }.map(&:first)
end
```

I don't know what the `(&:first)` is. I know what map does and it seems when I run:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5].chunk {|x| x}.map(&:first)
```

the duplicate elements are removed.

Comment: if the question is just about the &:first bit, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk), `chunk` enumerates over the items, chunking them together based on the return value of the block:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5].chunk {|x| x}.to_a
=> [[1, [1]],
    [2, [2]],
    [3, [3]], 
    [4, [4, 4]],
    [5, [5]]]
```

Then you choose only first element of each subarray:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5].chunk {|x| x}.map(&:first)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`map(&:first)` is just a shortcut for `map {|e| e.first}`

Comment: Or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5].chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)`

Comment: @steenslag neat! Ruby is so beautiful

Comment: In plain English : this method removes duplicates, but only if they're consecutive.