# print out elements with same index but from different arrays ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new at Ruby,
i'd like to know how can I get the first elements from different arrays (my arrays are a b c) and create a new one with them:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [:blue, :red, :yellow]
c = ["Tacos", "Burritos", "Chilli"]



new_array = [1,:blue,"Tacos"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `&:first`:

```
2.3.0 :037 > a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3]
2.3.0 :038 > b = [:blue, :red, :yellow]
 => [:blue, :red, :yellow]
2.3.0 :039 > c = ["Tacos", "Burritos", "Chilli"]
 => ["Tacos", "Burritos", "Chilli"]
2.3.0 :040 >
2.3.0 :041 >   [a,b,c].map(&:first)
 => [1, :blue, "Tacos"]
```

`map` returns an array of the input array, transformed by the specified logic.

`&:first` will call `first` on each element in the array `[a, b, c]` and return the first element of each array.

```
[a,b,c].map(&:first)
```

...is a shorthand for:

```
[a,b,c].map { |array| array.first }
```

Comment: What about if now i want to combine elements as a result, for example:
new_array = [2,:red,"Burritos"]

or

new_array = [2,:yellow,"Tacos"]

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
[a, b, c].map(&:first)
# => [1,:blue,"Tacos"]
```

Here, [map](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPvK3e6oLNAhUGsBQKHey-CCoQygQIIjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fruby-doc.org%2Fcore%2FEnumerable.html%23method-i-map&usg=AFQjCNHpRO1i8Kt7iuo0kr2Bidr8CcBhCA&sig2=e5yO9LQvM0NNW8MERpSq2g) iterates through the array of arrays, and returns a new array with the results of calling [first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) on each element.

The `&:first` is really just a shortcut for `{ |a| a.first }`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: Excellent!!!
What if i need now an array with the second or third elements from each array?

Comment: That is outside the scope of the original question and should be a separate question.  However, you should search StackOverflow for that question first -- it's likely that someone else has asked it and you would be a good SO citizen to minimize the number of duplicate questions.  BTW, please upvote any useful answers and select the checkmark for the best one -- it is suggested to wait a while before doing the latter for better answers to appear.

Comment: Well `first` is just a convenience method, for the first element. To access any arbitrary element, you would use the `[]` syntax. So for the third element of each array for example you could do `[a, b, c].map { |array| array[2] }`. Remember arrays in Ruby are zero-based, so index `[2]` refers to the third element. The first would be `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @KeithBennett :)

Comment: I would say a difference of 6 seconds is  a tie.