# Rails 4 Selecting uniq objects related AR CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I'm dealing with a shopping cart, which has many products in it. The products can be sold by multiple different companies. What I'm trying to do is select the companies uniquely so that I can create one order per vendor.

*the hack*

```
companies = []
@cart.products.each { |p| companies << p.company }
companies.uniq
#create order for each company
```

I'm not sure if `#pluck` is something I should be using here, but I do know that there has got to be a more efficient way of collecting my companies "uniquely". `#uniq` doesn't seem to be working for me, and neither does `@cart.products.pluck(:company)`

**I have no `:company_id` in my Bid model, it's a `has_many/has_one` relationship**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pluck` is used for retrieving array of values in provided column like:
`@cart.products.pluck(:company_id) # => [1,2,3]`

For collecting companies you can do `companies = @cart.products.collect(&:company).uniq`

Comment: Awesome, this works.. Can you clarify for me what the ampersand does? I've never really known when and when not to include it.

Comment: Sure thing. It's a shorthand for `@cart.products.collect(&:company.to_proc)`. It's equivalent to `@cart.products.collect {|prod| prod.company}`. This work only for objects that implement or inherit `to_proc` method. There is great explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby